# What is the difference between g++ and gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

What is the difference between g++ and gcc?  Which one of them should be used for general c++ development?

Answer (score 937, accepted):

`gcc` and `g++` are compiler-drivers of the GNU Compiler *Collection* (which was once upon a time just the GNU *C Compiler*).

Even though they automatically determine which backends (`cc1` `cc1plus` ...) to call depending on the file-type, unless overridden with `-x language`, they have some differences.

The probably most important difference in their defaults is which libraries they link against automatically.

According to GCC's online documentation [link options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) and [how g++ is invoked](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html), `g++` is *roughly* equivalent to `gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc` (the 1st is a compiler option, the 2nd two are linker options). This can be checked by running both with the `-v` option (it displays the backend toolchain commands being run).

By default (and unlike `gcc`), [g++ also adds linker option `-lm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c/1033940#1033940) -- to link against `libm` which contains implementations for `math.h`.

Comment: From this answer, I conclude that effectively g++  command is just gcc with a bunch of flags .. Why then, there are two different binaries(of approximately the same size )  for gcc and g++ in  linux ?. Shouldn't we have just one binary and one symlink(or something along those lines) ?

Comment: @Uchihaltachi these files are hard links and when they are booted up they check `argv[0]` to see which invocation should be used. This is pretty common among the core UNIX utilities.

Comment: Where does it say that `g++ is equivalent to gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc` in the docs? It says only that it treats .c, .h and .i as C++ and links libstdc++ automatically. If the command posted was the case, a .txt file with valid C++ code would compile but instead returns unsupported file format error.

Comment: This answer is WRONG . just try 
```# include <iostream>

int main ( ) {
 std :: cout << "hello" << std :: endl ;
}
```
I hope someone can make it compiled by gcc command line instead of g++.

Comment: @neoedmund [here.](https://tio.run/##HY1RCsIwEAX/c4pH/VFKLhCDd4mbtV3YJtCkIIhXd43@DcPAkF@IzE5SSI/MiFJb3zltNyelY0tScL7g5YDWcwhUj44YMa2sWqcfDo8QwCXr1b1h9qGHpqWZf9I8m9cR/KGtaefsVe7j@QU) (you're welcome! no need to thank me)

Comment: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/b1E3fYoT8) if still in doubt.

Comment: If g++ is equivalent to gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc, why we don't use gcc with a bunch flags instead of g++ all the time?

Comment: @Lyn: Probably for much the same reason we don't just use g++ with a bunch of flags instead of gcc.  Ba da boom.

Comment: I made a video to compare something between VS and GCC with a same C++ code. Someone commented it should be called g++ instead of gcc. But I think gcc is the compiler's name. g++ is a command for compiling c++ code. Is that right?

Comment: @Zhang after this heated argument in comment section if you still want to bring this up, fine, yes its g++ and it’s a compiler as well.

Comment: @user836218. On Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, g++ and gcc (9.4) are exactly the same size but don't seem to be hard links (ls -i points to different inodes). Also cmp says they're not identical.

Answer (score 573):

GCC: GNU Compiler Collection

- Referrers to all the different languages that are supported by the GNU compiler.

`gcc`: GNU C      Compiler
`g++`: GNU C++ Compiler

The main differences:

1. `gcc` will compile: `*.c\*.cpp` files as C and C++ respectively.
2. `g++` will compile: `*.c\*.cpp` files but they will all be treated as C++ files.
3. Also if you use `g++` to link the object files it automatically links in the std C++ libraries (`gcc` does not do this).
4. `gcc` compiling C files has fewer predefined macros.
5. `gcc` compiling `*.cpp` and `g++` compiling `*.c\*.cpp` files has a few extra macros.

Extra Macros when compiling `*.cpp` files:

```
#define __GXX_WEAK__ 1
#define __cplusplus 1
#define __DEPRECATED 1
#define __GNUG__ 4
#define __EXCEPTIONS 1
#define __private_extern__ extern
```

Comment: You can link the std C++ library in `gcc` by passing `-lstdc++` parameter.

Comment: There are more differences between 'gcc' and 'g++' than only the standard libraries, so `gcc -lstdc++` will still not get you the same behavior as `g++`.  We put all of that language-specific behavior into its own driver for a reason, that's what it's there for.  :-)

Comment: My comment isn't talking about just linking... that's the point.  Even just restricting the discussion to linking (which your answer was not), a user *still* won't be able to use the entire C++ standard library by only specifying `-lstdc++`, as there will be missing dependencies on math, RTTI, and exception information.  Whether a given test case links or fails will depend on the operating system and which C++ features are used by the test case, which again is why all of that knowledge is built into the g++ driver instead of being left up to the user to figure out.

Comment: Trust me, we have this discussion a lot, usually when a Linux user tries to move his incomplete Makefile to another platform.  :-)  The g++ link stage does a lot more than `gcc -lstdc++` on other OSes, especially when the target is an embedded platform.  Fortunately, that's why we ship a g++ in the first place.

Comment: The spec strings are constructed to be specific to the compiler, which in turn are specific to the operating system and target.  So if you run `-dumpspec` on (for example) a cross compiler targeting an embedded system, you will see the differences.  There are more than just linker differences... which again, is what your answer was about (preprocessor macros, include paths, multiple runtime libraries).  We seem to be talking past each other, but as a former GCC maintainer, I assure you I am familiar with what the frontends are and are not.

Comment: So, when there is a mix of both C, C++ code in a given application,  it seems to me that for compilation, C code should go to gcc, C++ to g++. But when it comes to linking(be it the dll, or the app executable), g++ is recommended. Have I got it right?

Comment: Also gcc might simply fail on some cpp files while g++ works with those without any issues..Even after using the -x flag for gcc to tell it it's cpp mode I want. I've just stumbled upon this and was actually quite surprised. Then again this comes from using frontends for compiling all the time. XD

Comment: The `__cplusplus` macro is not defined as 1, but rather as the language standard being used.

Comment: Point 2 is incorrect, the behaviour is the same as point 1.

Comment: @Clifford Just confirmed the above is correct. Save the following program `#include <stdio.h> int main() { fprintf(stdout, "%ld\n", sizeof('a')); return 0}` as C and C++. Then compile both files with `gcc` and `g++`. Should be four application. Only the C program compiled with the C compiler will generate `4` all the others are treated as C++ and will print `1`. One of the differences between C and C++ is that character literals are `int` in C while they are `char` in C++.

Comment: @MartinYork thanks.  Could perhaps more simply use `#if defined __cplusplus` to demonstrate the language compilation.

Comment: @Clifford Sure could. But still shows the same thing that the above is correct. :-)

Answer (score 120):

For c++ you should use g++.

It's the same compiler (e.g. the GNU compiler collection). GCC or G++ just choose a different front-end with different default options.

In a nutshell: if you use g++ the frontend will tell the linker that you may want to link with the C++ standard libraries. The gcc frontend won't do that (also it could link with them if you pass the right command line options).

Comment: +1 Also my GNU/Linux gcc man page says, "When you compile C++ programs, you should invoke GCC as g++ instead."

Answer (score 64):

**What is the difference between `g++` and `gcc`?**

`gcc` has evolved from a single language "GNU C Compiler" to be a multi-language "GNU Compiler Collection".  The term `gcc` may still sometimes refer to the "GNU C Compiler" in the context of C programming.

```sh
man gcc

# GCC(1)                     GNU
# 
# NAME
#        gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler
```

However, `g++` *is* the C++ compiler frontend for the GNU Compiler Collection. Like `gnat` is the Ada compiler frontend for `gcc`. [see Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html)

For example, the Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 `man g++` command returns the `GCC(1)` manual page.

The Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 `man gcc` states that ...

> `g++` accepts mostly the same options as `gcc`

and that the default ...

> ... use of `gcc` does not add the C++ library.  `g++` is a program
> that calls GCC and automatically specifies linking against the C++
> library.  It treats .c, .h and .i files as C++ source files instead of
> C source files unless -x is used.  This program is also useful when
> precompiling a C header file with a .h extension for use in C++
> compilations.

Search the `gcc` man pages for more details on the option variances between `gcc` and `g++`.

**Which one should be used for general c++ development?**

Technically, either `gcc` or `g++` can be used for general C++ development with applicable option settings.  However, the `g++` default behavior is naturally aligned to a C++ development.

The [Ubuntu 18.04 'gcc' man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gcc.1.html#description) added, and [Ubuntu 20.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gcc.1.html) … [Ubuntu 24.04](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/gcc.1.html) continue to have, the following paragraph:

> The usual way to run GCC is to run the executable called `gcc`, or `machine-gcc` when cross-compiling, or `machine-gcc-version` to run a specific version of GCC.  ***When you compile C++ programs, you should invoke GCC as `g++` instead.***

---

Side Note: In the case of the Xcode.app embedded toolchain, `g++` simply links to `gcc`. *Thus, `g++` invocations may vary on a per-toolchain basis.*

```bash
ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
# …
# lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         3 Apr 27  2021 g++ -> gcc
# -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    167120 Nov 23 20:51 gcc

### -- versus --
which -a g++
# /usr/bin/g++
ls -l /usr/bin/g++
# -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  137616 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/g++
```

Answer (score 31):

One notable difference is that if you pass a `.c` file to gcc it will compile as C.

The default behavior of g++ is to treat `.c` files as C++ (unless `-x c` is specified).

Answer (score 21):

Although the gcc and g++ commands do very similar things, g++ is designed to be the command you'd invoke to compile a C++ program; it's intended to automatically do the right thing.

Behind the scenes, they're really the same program.  As I understand, both decide whether to compile a program as C or as C++ based on the filename extension.  Both are capable of linking against the C++ standard library, but only g++ does this by default.  So if you have a program written in C++ that doesn't happen to need to link against the standard library, gcc will happen to do the right thing; but then, so would g++.  So there's really no reason not to use g++ for general C++ development.

Answer (score 14):

**I became interested in the issue and perform some experiments**

1. I found that description [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html), but it is very short.
2. Then I tried to experiment with gcc.exe and g++.exe on my windows machine:

   ```
   $ g++ --version | head -n1 
   g++.exe (gcc-4.6.3 release with patches [build 20121012 by perlmingw.sf.net]) 4.6.3

   $ gcc --version | head -n1
   gcc.exe (gcc-4.6.3 release with patches [build 20121012 by perlmingw.sf.net]) 4.6.3
   ```
3. I tried to compile c89, c99, and c++1998 simple test files and It's work well for me with correct extensions matching for language

   ```
   gcc -std=c99 test_c99.c
   gcc -std=c89 test_c89.c 
   g++ -std=c++98 test_cpp.cpp
   gcc -std=c++98 test_cpp.cpp
   ```
4. But when I try to run "gnu compiler collection" tool in that fashion:

   ```
   $ gcc -std=c++98 test_cpp.c
   cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-std=c++98' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]
   ```
5. But this one still work with no errors

   ```
   $ gcc -x c++ -std=c++98 test_cpp.c
   ```
6. And this also

   ```
   $ g++ -std=c++0x test_cpp_11.cpp
   ```

p.s. Test files

```
$ cat test_c89.c test_c99.c test_cpp.cpp

// C89 compatible file
int main()
{
    int x[] = {0, 2};
    return sizeof(x);
}

// C99 compatible file
int main()
{
    int x[] = {[1]=2};
    return sizeof(x);
}

// C++1998,2003 compatible file
class X{};
int main()
{
    X x;
    return sizeof(x);
}

// C++11
#include <vector>
enum class Color : int{red,green,blue}; // scoped enum
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a {1,2,3}; // bracket initialization
    return 0;
}
```

**Findings:**

1. If look at process tree then it seems that gcc, and g++ is backend to other tools, which in my environment are: *cc1plus.exe, cc1.exe, collect2.exe, as.exe, ld.exe*
2. gcc works fine as metatool for if you have correct extension or set correct
   -std -x flags. See [this](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

Answer (score 10):

“GCC” is a common shorthand term for the GNU Compiler Collection. This is both the most general name for the compiler, and the name used when the emphasis is on compiling C programs (as the abbreviation formerly stood for “GNU C Compiler”).

When referring to C++ compilation, it is usual to call the compiler “G++”. Since there is only one compiler, it is also accurate to call it “GCC” no matter what the language context; however, the term “G++” is more useful when the emphasis is on compiling C++ programs.

You could read more [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.5/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html).

Answer (score 0):

gcc and g ++ are both GNU compiler. They both compile c and c++. The difference is for *.c files gcc treats it as a c program, and g++ sees it as a c ++ program. *.cpp files are considered to be c ++ programs. c++ is a super set of c and the syntax is more strict, so be careful about the suffix.

Comment: C++ is a different language, not a strict superset of C, so compiling with the wrong target language might well produce unexpected results. Also note that `g++` will also interpret `.cc` as a C++-only filename extension.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing gcc and g++ in a linux system. By using MAKEFILE, I can define the compliler used by "GNU make". I tested with the so called "dynamic memory" locating feature of "C plus plus" by :

```
int main(){

int * myptr = new int;
* myptr = 1;
printf("myptr[0] is %i\n",*myptr);
return 0;
}
```

Only g++ can successfully compile on my computer while gcc will report error

```
undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
```

So my own conclusion is gcc does not fully support "C plus plus". **It seems that choosing g++ for C++ source files is a better option.**

Comment: You have to do two job: 1. select language 2. choose some library suhch as libstdc++

Answer (score -1):

g++ and gcc are both compilers provided by the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC), and the main difference lies in the languages they are primarily designed to compile.

gcc:

gcc is the GNU Compiler for C. It is primarily used for compiling C programs.
When you use gcc to compile a source file, it assumes that the code is written in C.

g++:

g++ is the GNU Compiler for C++. It is specifically designed for compiling C++ programs.
When you use g++ to compile a source file, it treats the code as C++ code, enabling C++ features and standards.

Comment: Actually they are different frontends for the same compiler.