# compiling c++ with gcc/g++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, gcc, programming-languages

I'm new to c++ and i want to compile my testprogram .
i have now 3 files **"main.cpp" "parse.cpp" "parse.h"**

how can i compile it with one command?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Compile them both at the same time and place result in a.out

```
$ g++ file.cpp other.cpp
```

Compile them both at the same time and place results in prog2

```
$ g++ file.cpp other.cpp -o prog2
```

Compile each separately and then link them into a.out

```
$ g++ -c file.cpp
$ g++ -c other.cpp
$ g++ file.o other.o
```

Compile each separately and then link them into prog2

```
$ g++ -c file.cpp
$ g++ -c other.cpp
$ g++ file.o other.o -o prog2
```

Comment: Voted up for clarity, but for anything more complex I would investigate makefiles

Comment: i agree with @ Brian Agnew . Its true .. When I will use make files . But for the small compiling . just using command is fine ...

Answer (score 8):

Typically you will use the [make utility](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?make) with a makefile.  [Here is a tutorial](http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm).

If you only want a simple compilation though you can just use gcc directly...

You don't specify the .h files as they are included by the .cpp files.

> gcc a.cpp b.cpp -o program.out
>   ./program.out

Comment: By the way see my previous question here to see the differences between g++ and gcc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc

Answer (score 3):

Using command line compilation is trivial for a simple basic program but it gets more difficult nor impossible when you'll try to compile a "real program". I mean not a big one a simple collection of various source files, libraries with some compiler options for example.

For this purposes there are various build systems and the one I recommend you is CMake.
It's an open source cross-platform build system very powerful and ease to use. 
I use it every day and I think it's more easy to use than other ones like the AutoTools

More information on: [www.cmake.org](http://www.cmake.org)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, if you use g++ compiler, you have to compile the main, using this command :

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

The result executable will be "main" in this case.
The option "-o" means that the compiler will optimize the compilation.
If you want to know more about theses options, look at the man pages (man g++).

Comment: The -o option sets the name of the output binary.

-On is for optimisation where n is a number from 0 to 4 or s depending on the optimisations required.