# When compiling on my Mac, i get this error when i use "gcc" to compile but not with clang++

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

i get this error when i try and compile my C++ code on Mac.
I've been programming for a while on PC but just got given a Mac laptop for UNI work and I'm getting used to it. I usually compile using "gcc" but it seems to not work. Any help would be appreciated. Until then ill just use "clang++" when compiling.

Alternatively, If i use "gcc" to compile and there are ERRORS in the code, it works perfectly. This only happens when there are NO ERRORS.

```css
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:C++ Michael$ cc HelloWorld.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in HelloWorld-97feed.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Your title says "gcc or cc" then your body says "gcc or g++". Which is it? What _exactly_ are you doing? Because to me it looks like you're trying to build a C++ program with a C compiler (e.g. `cc`) and thus missing the standard library implementation.

Comment: mistypes gcc in the title

Comment: Okay yet it says "cc" in your example, too. Please take some care over your post...

Comment: Note you can compile almost all `C++` files with `gcc` (or `clang` for that matter), if you link it against the `C++` runtime library, like this: `gcc -lc++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp`

Comment: But there's literally no reason to ever do that.

Answer (score 4):

`gcc`, `clang` and `cc` (which appears to be a symlink to `clang` on your system) are commands to build C programs.

`g++` and `clang++` are commands to build C++ programs.

C and C++ are two different languages.

And although all those commands are typically just "front doors" to a bigger compiler behind the scenes that is capable of building all sorts of stuff, there are certain defaults that depend on the actual command you entered. For example, executing `gcc` or `cc` will not automatically add the C++ standard library to the libraries being linked into your program.

*Read the documentation* and then use the correct command to build C++ programs in your toolchain. For Clang, that's `clang++` (as you've discovered). For GCC, that's `g++`.

- *See also:* [Difference between CC, gcc and g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1516609/560648)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure, as back when i first started c++ the instructions told me to either g++ or gcc and it would do the same thing. either that or i've remembered wrong.

Comment: @user3427318: The instructions may well have been wrong. It would not be unprecedented in the world of programming tuition.

Comment: Yea thats true, although compiling using gcc did work back then :\

Comment: @MichaelMariani: Probably you were only using standard library facilities that were defined in the headers, not in the binary runtime. So the missing lib didn't get diagnosed.

Comment: Thats possible, atleast i've sorted it out now nice and early so it doesn't become a habit

Comment: @MichaelMariani: Yep

Answer (score 2):

In previous versions of Xcode, apple used to ship both libstdc++ and libc++. In order to prevent name-clashes, the maintainers of libc++ alias the std:: namespace to std::__1.

What is happening is that g++ (which defaults to using libstdc++) is linking against libraries that have been compiled with clang (which defaults to libc++)

In fact, stdlibc++ is still shipped with Xcode but as far as I can tell it's out of date.

confused?

So was I.

Unless you know exactly what you're doing, it's best to compile everything with clang++ on a mac. In fact, later versions of Xcode treat g++ as a synonym for clang++.