# getenv("cc") is returning NULL , why?

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc, cc

I am learning C and came across `cc` in the bash shell i.e. whenever I `make` my source files I see this command.

Hence started to understand it,started with `gcc --help`  but couldn't find `cc` option in the help. So started surfing the net, and came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516609/difference-between-cc-gcc-and-g). In the second answer it says `cc` is an environment variable and often points to `/usr/bin/gcc` on Linux systems.

I am using Linux distro and when I print return value from `getenv("cc")`, I am getting `NULL`. Why is this happening?

Comment: try to run `env` on the shell you're invoking your C program with. Do you get that `cc` variable?
CC is an automatic variable from gnu make: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Comment: No, it says CC is an environment variable. Not cc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cc` is usually not an environment variable.  There is commonly a symbolic link `/usr/bin/cc` which points at `gcc`.

Answer (score 2):

"cc" is a c compiler (executable), its not exposed as an environment variable ... getenv will print env variables

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [cc](/questions/tagged/cc):

> cc is a common name for a C compiler executable or driver. It is the default for the $(CC) make variable.

---

Because, as the [ref](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getenv.html) states:

> If the specified name cannot be found in the environment of the calling process, a null pointer shall be returned.

---

Moreover, if you run `env` on a terminal, will you see `cc`? Not really! That's why you get a `NULL` pointer. Since it doesn't seem to be an *environment variable*..

---

I believe that the `cc` you mention is something like this in your makefile:

```
CC=gcc
```

something [usual in Makefiles](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).