# How are Make, Makefile, cc, and gcc connected in Linux? How to know what 'make' will do with a .c file? (Will 'make' call cc or gcc?)

Tags: linux, makefile, gcc

I am trying to learn C and just started the book "Learn C the Hard Way." In the second lesson the author mentions Makefiles and states that when using the command "make example.c", 'make' will automatically call cc to build the .c file. Out of curiosity, I started to investigate cc since I was only familiar with gcc. According to user Jonathan Leffler on SO's post "[Difference between CC, gcc and g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516609/difference-between-cc-gcc-and-g)", cc usually links to gcc in Linux.

So here are my questions:

1) How does cc link to gcc in Linux? It seems like a simple question but I can't tell if it would require a basic answer or an advanced OS answer. (It seems that cc isn't an environmental variable as one user claimed on SO after checking with "env >> env_vars.txt" on Red Hat Linux and then reading the contents of the text file env_vars.txt.)

2) How do we know the internal details of what 'make' will do when it encounters a .c file (or any other file)? For example, in the case of .c files, how exactly can we know or confirm that 'make' will call cc as opposed to directly calling gcc with a .c file (or not)? (Does 'make' reference a default Makefile? If so, how can we read the contents of this default Makefile?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't answer for all Linuxes, but hopefully this will give you enough to determine the answers for your own system.

> 1. How does cc link to gcc

We can use

```
$ type cc
cc is /usr/bin/cc
```

So what is `/usr/bin/cc`?

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/cc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jun 29  2016 /usr/bin/cc -> /etc/alternatives/cc
```

so it's a *symbolic link* - but one that's managed by the `alternatives` system. We can query that:

```
$ update-alternatives --query cc
Name: cc
Link: /usr/bin/cc
Slaves:
 cc.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/cc.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/gcc
Value: /usr/bin/gcc

Alternative: /usr/bin/clang
Priority: 10
Slaves:

Alternative: /usr/bin/gcc
Priority: 20
Slaves:
 cc.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
```

So `cc` is indeed linked to `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Note that `/usr/bin/gcc` may itself be a symbolic link - to s specific version of `gcc`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Feb 11  2016 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-5
```

> 2. How do we know the internal details of what 'make' will do when it encounters a .c file

Given a file `hello.c` then we can check what `make` will do using the `-n` option:

```
$ make -n hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
```

Beyond that, you can refer to the documentation for your system's version of `make` - for example [GNU make: Catalogue of Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I spent hours on the Linux 'man'/manual pages and with Google searches to no avail and appreciate your explanation and information.

Comment: A process can read the command that invoked it. This means it can distinguish if it was called as `cc` or `gcc` and do different things depending on how you started it. You may not be able to replace `cc` with `gcc`. Check the man page. At the moment, `man cc`gives you the man page to `gcc`, so they are currently interchangeable.