# Set the default GCC to Xcode Command Line Tools

Tags: xcode, gcc, anaconda, macos-catalina

**How can I ensure that `gcc` points to a particular compiler? Can I make a permanent symbolic link to the `xcode` version of `gcc`?**

I have several versions of the `gcc` compiler installed on my system, including

```
`gcc-11` found at `/usr/local/gcc-10/share` (compiled from source following these [instructions][1])
`gcc-9.3.0` found at `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/share`
`gcc-4.8.5` found at `/Users/PatrickT/miniconda/pkgs/gcc-4.8.5-8/share`
```

The default version is gcc-4:

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
which gcc
/Users/PatrickT/miniconda/bin/gcc
```

This miniconda version of `gcc` is not working for me. If I remove miniconda from the PATH, my system reverts to another version of `gcc` and everything works as expected. However, I do use miniconda's Python and would therefore like to keep it on my PATH. In my `.zhrc` profile (apparently, MacOS Catalina has moved the `.bashrc` to `.zhrc`), I have:

```
export PATH="/Users/PatrickT/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/gcc-10/bin:$PATH"
```

I have tried to change the order of these lines, but it has made no difference: miniconda's `gcc` remains the default compiler, unless I remove the first line completely, but then... I'm unable to use conda's Python!

Background: I'm not using the `gcc` directly, but I appear to need it to compile certain scripts. I have both the `xcode` command line tools and the `xcode` application, if that matters. I'm on ***MacOS Catalina 10.15.4***.

Comment: Your problem is a perfect example why making conda available via `conda init <shell-name>` is preferable over adding `<miniconda-root>/bin` to your path directly. :-)

Comment: I must admit that I am not very familiar with the mechanism spyder finds conda environments, but I am fairly confident it will work fine with the new `conda init` way of making conda available. Note, that the preferred way to make conda available used to be putting `<miniconda-root>/bin` into PATH, that's why you found the comment there. See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#conda-init for details.

Comment: @cel, Thanks for the tips. I have cleaned up my system as much as I could by removing and reinstalling compilers and Python distributions. It took a great deal of slewthing to find and remove/change symlinks to old things. I am currently using a conda environment, but I'm not sure how much that helps... The Anaconda/Miniconda docs recommend setting up an environment and not adding to PATH, but then it complains that you have to run  `conda init` and that puts conda on the PATH. Oh well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until a better solution comes along, you can remove Anaconda's `gcc` with

```
    conda remove gcc
```

And check that your system is now picking up from `Xcode`

```
    gcc --version
    Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Until a knowledgeable person answers this question, here is some food for thought:

- `cc` is a symbolic link to `gcc`.
- `CC` is an environment variable referring to the system's `C` compiler.
- `gcc` is a symbolic link to a compiler.
- A typical default is `CC=cc`, where `cc` is usually a symlink to `gcc`.
- You can change the invocation for a particular task by setting  `CC?=gcc` or `CC=gcc`. The `?=' operator is a conditional variable assignment operator: will have an effect only if the variable`CC`is not yet defined. The`=`operator will supersede any previously set link. Or`CC=gcc-10` to invoke a particular version insalled on your system.
- `CC` could be a link to `clang` (MacOS) or `g++` (Linux). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516609/difference-between-cc-gcc-and-g) to a related question, particularly Jonathan Leffler's answer and the comment by Josh Kodroff.

References: [GNU Manual on Implicit Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html), [GNU Manual on Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).