# Should I use gcc or cc when programming in C?

Tags: c, gcc, cc

I searched a little bit and one google search was enough to discover the **differences** between the gcc and cc compilers, but I did not find the advantages in using one or another to compile C programs

Which compiler should I use? and why?

Comment: What does `cc --version` report and what does `gcc --version` report?

Comment: Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
\n Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0
\n Thread model: posix
\n InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: i used \n to indicate where are the line breaks

Comment: why gcc? it reports almost the same thing

Comment: If `gcc` reports the same as `cc` something must have gone wrong upon installation. `gcc` is _not_ a clang based compiler.

Comment: its not exactly the same, it reports some aditional things at the beggining

Comment: On Apple, gcc is a link to clang.

Comment: Anyway... You'll be fine with either one. On iOS I think the clang based is what people usually use.

Comment: hmmm i just updated xcode, does it have something to do with that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516609/difference-between-cc-gcc-and-g . Although that doesn't describe "cc" and "gcc" on macos.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler installed as part of X-Code on OS/X is a recent version of **clang** whose development is sponsored by Apple.

**gcc** is not provided nor supported by Apple.

Unless you install **gcc** explicitly from one of its distributions, `gcc` is an alias for `clang` on OS/X, just like `cc`.

The reason for this is to support packages that use `gcc` explicitly as the C compiler.

On your system, it does not matter which alias you use, the compiler invoked will be clang, which has a high degree of compatibility with gcc extensions but generates different code.  Both are very advanced and dependable.