# What is the difference between g++ and c++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“g++” and “c++” compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712756/g-and-c-compiler)

What is the difference between `g++` and `c++` compilers?
Which of them I must use?

I mean i can write `с++ test.cpp` or `g++ test.cpp` and i receive same executable files.
I checked their `md5sum` they are same too like a size of this files.
So i want uderstand what the difference.