# develop C++ without Xcode IDE

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, operating-system, max

I want to develop C++ programs on mac os and I have installed Xcode with a bunch of frameworks.

However I would like to write code without Xcode **IDE** but just write my own makefile and directly compile/link with gcc (shipped with Xcode).

Take a opengl program as example. I tried to compile it with the command:

> gcc  -I/usr/include/
>   -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Headers/
>   -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers
>   -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11/lib/  -L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries/
>   -lGL -lGLU -lGLUTt  main.cpp

or

> gcc  -I/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib
>   -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lm  main.cpp

But they ended up with linking error

> Undefined symbols:
>   "std::basic_ostream
>
> > ::operator<<(long)", referenced from:
> >           reshape(int, int)in ccKBRSF9.o
> >           display()    in ccKBRSF9.o   "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced
> >     from:
> >           ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in ccKBRSF9.o
> >          (maybe you meant: ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr)   "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()",
> >     referenced from:
> >           ___tcf_0 in ccKBRSF9.o   "std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator
> >     ::operator[](unsigned long) const", referenced from:
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in
> >     ccKBRSF9.o
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in
> >     ccKBRSF9.o
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in
> >     ccKBRSF9.o   "std::basic_ostream >&
> >     std::operator<<
> >     
> >     (std::basic_ostream >&, char
> >     const*)", referenced from:
> >           keyboard(unsigned char, int, int)in ccKBRSF9.o
> >           keyboard(unsigned char, int, int)in ccKBRSF9.o
> >           keyboard(unsigned char, int, int)in ccKBRSF9.o
> >           reshape(int, int)in ccKBRSF9.o
> >           display()    in ccKBRSF9.o   "std::ios_base::Init::Init()",
> >     referenced from:
> >           __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccKBRSF9.o
> >     "std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator >::size() const",
> >     referenced from:
> >           std::__verify_grouping(char const*, unsigned long,
> >     std::basic_string,
> >     std::allocator > const&)in
> >     ccKBRSF9.o   "std::cout", referenced
> >     from:
> >           __ZSt4cout$non_lazy_ptr in ccKBRSF9.o
> >          (maybe you meant: __ZSt4cout$non_lazy_ptr) ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit
> >     status

Did I miss something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `g++` to compile C++.  It's the C++ front-end for GCC.  E.g.:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lm main.cpp
```

Comment: Because gcc is a C compiler, and it will not properly link in the C++ standard library.

Comment: @elgcom: This is the same of GCC on all platforms.

Comment: If you insist then you can still use gcc if you add `-lstdc++`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `clang++`, but in both cases you will have to use the `C++` compiler, or the `-lstdc++` option.