# Problem occurred while compiling a cpp program in gcc

Tags: c++

My code is

```
#include<iostream>   

using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
   cout <<"hi";  
   return 0;  
}
```

I compile it with:

```
gcc d.cpp -o d
```

Error as follows

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator [](unsigned int) const/var/tmp//ccyDVhhA.o
std::cout                           /var/tmp//ccyDVhhA.o
std::ios_base::Init::~Init()        /var/tmp//ccyDVhhA.o
std::ios_base::Init::Init()         /var/tmp//ccyDVhhA.o
__gxx_personality_v0                /var/tmp//ccyDVhhA.o
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_tr aits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)/va r/tmp//ccyDVhhA.o
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() c onst/var/tmp//ccyDVhhA.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to d
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the mistake in the above code?

Comment: I can't how many times I've seen similar errors when I was moving from c to c++

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc/173007#173007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g++ d.cpp -o d
```

Should use g++ for a c++ program <s>compilation</s> to link to C++ standard library.

Comment: Wait, really? I thought GCC autodetects the type? (I tried compiling a Java file and it said Java isn't supported...)

Comment: @Mehrdad - I amn't sure whether we could configure gcc to do that. But by default, it cannot link to C++ libraries.

Comment: @Mahesh: Yeah, weird... interesting.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It does. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc/173007#173007

Comment: @Martin: Doesn't the link say, `gcc will compile: *.c/*.cpp files as C and C++ respectively.`?

Answer (score 3):

You should compile your C++ programs with `g++`, not `gcc`. There is no mistake in the code, but if you use gcc with those parameters then your program will not be linked against the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

that code should compile fine with a c++ compiler, however you are compiling it using gcc (a c compiler) need to use g++