# What's the difference between gcc and g++/gcc-c++?

Tags: gcc, g++

It seems to me that gcc can deal with both c and c++ projects,so why is g++/gcc-c++ needed?

What's the difference between g++ and gcc-c++?

Comment: gcc-c++ doesn't seem to be a standard compiler name, at least now. Googling for it, I get this question as the top link to actually contain that string, and the only other is a package listed on rpmfind.net. So I have no idea what it was... could have been as little as a symlink.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`gcc` will compile C source files as C and C++ source files as C++ if the file has an appropriate extension; however it will not link in the C++ library automatically.

`g++` will automatically include the C++ library; by default it will also compile files with extensions that indicate they are C source as C++, instead of as C.

From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b:

> C++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes `.C`, `.cc`, `.cpp`, `.CPP`, `.c++`, `.cp`, or `.cxx`; C++ header files often use `.hh`, `.hpp`, `.H`, or (for shared template code) `.tcc`; and preprocessed C++ files use the suffix `.ii`. GCC recognizes files with these names and compiles them as C++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for compiling C programs (usually with the name gcc).
>
> However, the use of gcc does not add the C++ library. g++ is a program that calls GCC and treats `.c`, `.h` and `.i` files as C++ source files instead of C source files unless -x is used, and automatically specifies linking against the C++ library. This program is also useful when precompiling a C header file with a `.h` extension for use in C++ compilations.

For example, to compile a simple C++ program that writes to the `std::cout` stream, I can use either (MinGW on Windows):

- g++ -o test.exe test.cpp
- gcc -o test.exe test.cpp -lstdc++

But if I try:

- gcc -o test.exe test.cpp

I get undefined references at link time.

And for the other difference, the following C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int* new;
    int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *p = 42;
    new = p;

    printf("The answer: %d\n", *new);

    return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs fine using:

- gcc -o test.exe test.c

But gives several errors when compiled using:

- g++ -o test.exe test.c

Errors:

```
test.c: In function 'int main()':
test.c:6:10: error: expected unqualified-id before 'new'
test.c:6:10: error: expected initializer before 'new'
test.c:7:32: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*'
test.c:10:9: error: expected type-specifier before '=' token
test.c:10:11: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
test.c:12:36: error: expected type-specifier before ')' token
```

Comment: because it's using "new" as a variable name, ho ho.

Comment: What kind of a programmer uses "new" as a variable name? What I'm wondering more, is how did you compile that abomination successfully using gcc...

Comment: @JohnJohn That was just an example of valid C (but invalid C++) code, and that's why gcc compiles it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, g++ uses the correct C++ linker options whereas gcc uses the C linker options (so you may get undefined references, etc.).

Comment: @gdb: Interesting, I usually had issues, though I'm guessing you probably fixed them through passing in the correct flags manually.

Comment: probably.Also,what's the difference between g++ and gcc-c++?

Comment: @gdb: I'm confused... wasn't that your original question?