# Do I need to do something special to get my C++ program to compile using gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Why does my program compile nicely with no warnings when I type `g++ program_name` but when I type `gcc program_name` I get screenfuls of undefined reference errors...

I am using the standard library quite a bit, here are my includes:

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;
```

The reason I ask is I spent all this time developing a solution for a codeeval.com challange.  It works perfectly when compiled with g++, but won't compile with gcc.

Long story short, when codeeval tries to run my stuff, I get a score of 0 (!) although I have no idea how they are going about testing submissions...  They just say: `Your program did not pass all the test cases or there may have been warnings printed out at runtime`.

Of course, I have no idea how they are compiling it...  They do say:

`You submissions are executed in a *NIX type environment. Assume softwares/shells etc are in their standard locations. Nothing else.`

(since the have a typo in their submission guidlines, might other stuff be up?)

They also say they accept solutions for C++ 4.3.4.  I am running cywin and 4.3.4 is the version of my gcc.

Has anyone else ever had a problem with submitting C++ code to codeeval.com?

I'm trying not to be super frustrated, but at this point they seem more like codeevil.com to me...

Comment: C++ code is compiled only with g++. gcc is meant for C code.

Comment: `man gcc` says 'gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler'

Comment: g++ is for c++ and comes on top of gcc. You can check the tool size of both gcc and g++ to come to this conclusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between gcc and g++/gcc-c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853664/whats-the-difference-between-gcc-and-g-gcc-c)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem with codeeval.com - if you have C++ code and you select the C++ option on the codeeval page, it works - right?

Comment: @Michael:  That's the problem.  I selected C++ and all I get is the info I posted above..  with a score of zero.  But my program works for me (and is awesome!) I did read a bit on their forum that 'input is a nightmare' because no one knows what assumptions to make..  This is a proper generic way to open a file given at the command line right?  

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 ifstream input;
 input.open(argv[1]);
...
I wonder if I need to open it read-only?

Comment: @Jimmy: given your comment, I don't think this is a problem with how the compiler is invoked, but rather with how the program is run (probably 'nightmare inputs' as you mention). One thing you might try is to run a program that simply dumps `argv` and/or the input file  (maybe only some part of it, - I imagine they limit output) to see if that's the problem you're running into. By the way, I really hate how codeeval just wipes the editor clean when I change the language selection - really irritating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc doesnt link in the standard c++ libraries by default. Either add -lstdc++ to the link line, or just compile with g++.

Comment: Yeah, but I just submit the .cpp file, and they take care of building and linking it... Is there a standard location for the c++ header files in a *nix environment? Do I need to put the full path in my include statements? What I have written is generic right? Any ideas on why my code would be failing in the build process that codeval uses?

Comment: @Jimmy: Have you asked the people at codeeval about the problem?  They would be more likely to have the answer to this.

Comment: @Benjamin: just contacted them... my fault for having the stackoverflow twitch :) you guys are always just so much better and faster... This question can probably be deleted, but how else to get the word out that gcc can compile c++ code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, "gcc" is the Gnu C compiler, and "g++" the corresponding C++ compiler.  Personally, I prefer to use the former for C, the latter for C++, instead of relying on file suffixes or command line arguments.