# Why can't I compile HelloWorld in C++?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, g++

I'm trying to compile a simple Hello World program in C++ but I keep getting the following error...why?

```
gcc -o HelloWorldCompiled HelloWorld.cc
/tmp/ccvLW1ei.o: In function `main':
HelloWorld.cc:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
HelloWorld.cc:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char,     std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/tmp/ccvLW1ei.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
HelloWorld.cc:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
HelloWorld.cc:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccvLW1ei.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `g++` not `gcc`. gcc is a C compiler, whereas g++ is a C++ compiler.

```
g++ -o hwcompiled helloworld.cc
```

Then to execute your compiled program:

```
./hwcompiled
```

Comment: Thanks...what's the difference?

Comment: gcc is a C compiler, g++ is a C++ compiler

Comment: g++ is probably just an alias for gcc...you can actually use gcc to compile c++ i think by using the `-x c++` command-line option...

Comment: Technically gcc is the frontend for several compilers and linker tools but to ensure you get the right arguments you might as well use the right alias ... oh and it's `-lstdc++` to link with gcc.

Comment: `g++` will pull in the C++ library automatically.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5854712/12711 for too much detail.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `g++`, not `gcc`. It seems that `gcc` understands that it's C++ (so it doesn't give syntax errors), but "forgets" to link it to the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `g++` to compile your C++ code, instead of `gcc`, which is used for compiling C programs.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could still use `gcc` but explicitly link with the c++ library thusly:

```
gcc -o HelloWorldCompiled HelloWorld.cc -lstdc++
```