# gcc compilation error, works fine in Visual studio 2008 C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

Getting compilation error in gcc, even though it works fine on Visual Studio C++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;  // tried it, didn't work
using std::cin;   // tried it, didn't work
using std::endl;  // tried it, didn't work

using namespace std;
```

This is the error, I am getting while trying to compile it.

```
hw2_part2.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `std::cout'
hw2_part2.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
hw2_part2.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `std::cout'
hw2_part2.cpp:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
hw2_part2.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `std::cout'
hw2_part2.cpp:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
hw2_part2.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `std::cin'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compile using `g++` instead of `gcc` so you get the C++ library linked in.

See [What's the difference between gcc and g++/gcc-c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853664/whats-the-difference-between-gcc-and-g-gcc-c) for more details if you're interested (though there's really not much more to it).