# Inheritance in C++ not working. Linker error occured while compiling the below C++ code

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a C++ program. I am learning the "virtual functions" concept. So I was trying to see what happens when we override a function without making it "virtual".
I have three directories headers, sources and objects.
In the header directory, I have 2 files, Pokemon.h and Charmander.h  .
In the sources directory, I have 3 files Pokemon.cpp, Charmander.cpp and Main.cpp.
class Charmander in Charmander.h, inherits from class Pokemon from Pokemon.h.

This is Pokemon.h  in the "headers" directory:

```
/********************************************************************************
 * Pokemon --                                                                   *
 * This is the base class for all pokemons. Every pokemon will inherit from     *
 * this class.                                                                  *
 *                                                                              *
 * Author -- Aditya R.Singh                                                     *
 * Version -- 1.0                                                               *
 * Since -- 2014-06-21                                                          *
 ********************************************************************************/ 



#ifndef POKEMON_H
#define POKEMON_H



using namespace std;



class Pokemon {

    public:
        string type();
        string attack();
        string weakness();
};    



#endif
```

This is Charmander.h in the "headers" directory:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Charmander --                                                               *
 * This class is the derived class from class Pokemon. This is specialized for *
 * the pokemon Charmander.                                                     *
 *                                                                             *
 * Author -- Aditya R.Singh                                                    *
 * Version -- 1.0                                                              *
 * Since -- 2014-06-18                                                         *
 *******************************************************************************/



#ifndef CHARMANDER_H
#define CHARMANDER_H



#include "Pokemon.h"  



using namespace std;



class Charmander: public Pokemon {

    public:
        string type();
        string attack();
        string weakness();
};    



#endif
```

This is the Pokemon.cpp in the "sources" directory:

```
/**********************************************************************************
 * Pokemon --                                                                     *
 * This is the implementation of functions in class Pokemon.                      *
 * This is a generic class for every pokemon.                                     *
 *                                                                                *
 * Author -- Aditya R.Singh                                                       *
 * Since -- 1.0                                                                   *
 * Version -- 2014-06-21                                                          *
 **********************************************************************************/



#include <iostream>
#include "../headers/Pokemon.h"



using namespace std;



string Pokemon::type() {

    return "Normal";
}    



string Pokemon::attack() {

    return "Headbutt";
}



string Pokemon::weakness() {

    return "Fighting";
}
```

This is the Charmander.cpp file in the "sources" directory:

```
/**********************************************************************************
 * Charmander --                                                                  *
 * This is the Charmander class's functions implementations.                      *
 * This is specific to Charmander.                                                *
 *                                                                                *
 * Author -- Aditya R.Singh                                                       *
 * Since -- 1.0                                                                   *
 * Version -- 2014-06-21                                                          *
 **********************************************************************************/



#include <iostream>
#include "../headers/Charmander.h"



using namespace std;



string Charmander::type() {

    return "Fire";
} 



string Charmander::attack() {

    return "Fireflame";
}



string Charmander::weakness() {

    return "Water";
}
```

And this is the Main.cpp file in the "sources" directory:

```
/**********************************************************************************
 * Main --                                                                        *
 * This program will show the use of Polymorphism and Inheritance in C++.         *
 *                                                                                *
 * Author -- Aditya R.Singh                                                       *
 * Since -- 1.0                                                                   *
 * Version -- 2014-06-21                                                          *
 **********************************************************************************/



#include <iostream>
#include "../headers/Pokemon.h"
#include "../headers/Charmander.h"



using namespace std;



int main() {

    Pokemon *charmander = new Charmander;   



    cout << "Charmander is a " << charmander->type() << " type pokemon." << endl;
    cout << "Charmander can do a " << charmander->attack() << " attack." << endl;
    cout << "Charmander is weak against " << charmander->weakness() << " type pokemon." << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Now I compiled the Pokemon.cpp and put the object file in the "objects" directory... Currently my terminal is in the "Program" directory...

```
gcc -c sources/Pokemon.cpp -o objects/Pokemon.o
```

I compiled the Charmander.cpp and the put the object file in the "objects" directory... like this ..

```
gcc -c sources/Charmander.cpp -o objects/Charmander.o
```

It's working fine uptill now. I have the object files in the "objects" directory now.

But now I am trying to compile my Main.cpp like this..

```
gcc sources/Main.cpp -o Main objects/Pokemon.o objects/Charmander.o
```

But my GCC compiler gives some big error stack like, undefined symbols for architecture x86_64.

I am using a mac book pro, 64 bit machine. OS Mac OS X maverics.

Comment: You should post the error message, or at least some of it.

Comment: Even if this "works", I expect you should `#include <string>` before using the string type - not sure that's your problem, as you haven't provided the error messages.

Comment: You're learning C++, but you then enter the world of Java programming by doing this: `Pokemon *charmander = new Charmander;`  In C++, there is no need to use `new` to create an object.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other files called Pokemon.h . The Charmander.h's `#include "Pokemon.h" ` will search the same way that it does from your .cpp files, if you also had Pokemon.h in the sources then it finds that first. Actually things are a lot simpler if you put source and headers in the same directory; and you can symlink them to another directory if you want external access.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I tried that. but still the same error persists.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie maybe you overlooked that he wants polymorphism?

Comment: @MattMcNabb But I want to keep them separate. Coz of I don't know why. I have seen people doing it. And I too feel convenient that way.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - Yes, I see that now.  What is missing is the call to `delete`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What is the delete thing you talking about? And i used the **new** keyword coz I did not want to create a Charmander object separately and make it point by Pokemon class variable.

Comment: @Aditya In C++ when you allocate memory with `new`, you're supposed to deallocate the memory using `delete`.  Otherwise you will get a memory leak.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh yeah! Thanks for the tip. Heard that for the first time. Can you give me the syntax?

Comment: @Aditya - Where did you learn `new`?  Wherever it was, that same source of information should have had `delete` explained to you.

Comment: Have you heard of copyright - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pok%C3%A9mon_Company

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I saw the `new` keyword on the internet somewhere. They did not have anything like `delete`.

Comment: @EdHeal Dude, This is just an example, for educational purpose. Relax.

Comment: @Aditya - C++ is a language that can't be learned in an ad-hoc manner.  There will be other issues that you won't know about if you just learn "by ear".

Comment: @Aditya - Using a copyright without may land you in hot water. Educational or otherwise. I am relaxed but using copyright material is on your shoulders. Not mine

Comment: @EdHeal. it's fine. I don't think they would mind.

Comment: @Aditya - Well ask them! Perhaps they might mind. Me for  one with my copyright mind. It is my income

Comment: I think they would like it seeing people getting educated using their pokemons. lol

Comment: @EdHeal I see no copyright issues here. Perhaps you meant trademark issues?

Comment: @MattMcNabb - Either way you are on dodgy ground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `g++` instead of `gcc`  to compile and link C++ programs so that the C++ library gets properly linked in.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5854712/12711 for the gory details.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!! This was the exact problem I had. Oh yeah! Thankyou! Thankyou! Thankyou! Uhh! How careless...... :D :D :D I never made that mistake before. Don't know why it happened this time. lol. Thankyou.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

To get polymorphic behaviour, the base class must have at least one virtual function.

Add to the class definition of Pokemon:

```
virtual ~Pokemon() { }
```

Note that since your other functions are not virtual, `charmander->type()` will call `Pokemon::type()`, not `Charmander::type()`.

NB. Your code compiles correctly for me, with the addition of `#include <string>`. If you still have problems then try moving everything to the same directory , in case you are perhaps having one unit pick up an old version of a header file from a different directory.

Comment: Thanks, So what changes should I make in my code/s?  Infact, I want it to call type() from Pokemon class using the Charmander object. Coz I want to demo a call to a non virtual function.

Comment: yes, I did. thanks. actually I was using a gcc compiler in place of g++.

Comment: OK. Start a new question for things that aren't directly related to this question. And accept the answer of the guy who answered corectly!