# Is `g++` just `gcc -lstdc++`?

Tags: gcc, g++

Is there any difference between `g++` and `gcc -lstdc++`?

That is, is `g++` just `gcc` with the C++ standard library linked by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between gcc and g++/gcc-c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853664/whats-the-difference-between-gcc-and-g-gcc-c)

Answer (score 3):

g++ is a compiler, like gcc. g++ however includes the ability to parse modern C++ constructs, whereas gcc can do *some* of these, but is not intended for it.

-lstdc++ and gcc allows the compilation of libraries that use c++ specific runtime interfaces with your C code (gcc).

An example of this is a C application that needs to use a C++ library without needing to completely remake the C application into a C++ one to interface with it.