# Why use 'g++' instead of 'gcc' to compile *.cc files?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, compilation

I compiled a library which used `g++` instead of `gcc`. First I thought the source code was written in C++, but I found out later that there was not any C++ code in the *.cc files.

To confirm this, I replaced the `g++` in the original makefile with `gcc`. And I still got the correct program.

What is the explanation? It was not the first time I met such a situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you changed in the makefile.  `gcc` / `g++` is really just a front-end driver program which invokes the actual compiler and / or linker based on the options you give it.

If you invoke the compiler as `gcc`:

- it will *compile* as C or C++ based on the file extension (`.c`, or `.cc` / `.cpp`);
- it will *link* as C, i.e. it will not pull in C++ libraries unless you specifically add additional arguments to do so.

If you invoke the compiler as `g++`:

- it will *compile* as C++ regardless of whether or not the file extension is `.c` or `.cc` / `.cpp`;
- it will *link* as C++, i.e. automatically pull in the standard C++ libraries.

(see [the relevant bit of the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b)).

---

Here's a simple program which detects whether or not it has been compiled as C or C++.

(It makes use of the fact that a character constant has the size of an `int` in C, or a `char` in C++.  `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition; `sizeof(int)` will generally be larger - unless you're using an obscure platform with >= 16-bit bytes, which you're probably not.)

I've called it `test.c` and copied it as `test.cc` as well:

#### File *test.c*

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("I was compiled as %s!\n", sizeof('a') == 1 ? "C++" : "C");
  return 0;
}
```

#### Copy

```
cp test.c test.cc
```

Compiling and linking `test.c` with `gcc`, and `test.cc` with `g++`, works as expected:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c

$ ./test
I was compiled as C!

$ g++ -o test test.cc

$ ./test
I was compiled as C++!
```

Compiling and linking `test.cc` with `gcc` doesn't work: it compiles the code as C++ because the file ends in `.cc`, but fails at the link stage:

```
gcc -o test test.cc
```

Output:

```
/tmp/ccyb1he5.o:(.eh_frame+0x11): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

which we can prove by separately compiling with `gcc`, and linking with `g++` (to pull in the right libraries):

```
$ gcc -c test.cc

$ g++ -o test test.o

$ ./test
I was compiled as C++!
```

...`gcc` has compiled the code as C++ rather than C, because it had a `.cc` file extension.

Whereas `g++` does *not* compile `.c` files as plain C:

```
$ g++ -o test test.c

$ ./test
I was compiled as C++!
```

Comment: Very good answer and I have tried your test code on my machine.  Still one question, as you said gcc won't succeed at the linking stage for cc files, which is proved by your test code. In my makefile the compiling uses the gcc but the linking stage uses the gcc as well:

CXXLD = $(CXX)
CXXLINK = $(LIBTOOL) --tag=CXX $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) \
 --mode=link $(CXXLD) $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(AM_LDFLAGS) \
 $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

where CXX is gcc (I replaced g++ with gcc)

but it still got the correct result.

Comment: @deepsky: If the code is compiled with the right options, it may not introduce any dependencies on the libraries that don't get linked.  In my example above, the complaint is about something in the `.eh_frame` section, which is related to exception handling support:  on my system I find that `gcc -fno-exceptions -o test test.cc` *does* work OK.  (Running `./test` still reveals that it was compiled as C++, not C.)

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the .cc code *happens* to be C, but was intended to be linked into a C++ library. The internals are different.

Answer (score 1):

`g++` automatically links the C++ runtime library—`gcc` doesn't. Obviously, when it doesn't matter—then it doesn't matter, but, as already [pointed out by spraff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626363/why-use-g-instead-of-gcc-to-compile-cc-files/6626444#6626444), it could be intended for future use.

Comment: Also the "linkage" is different...  The C++ compiler will mangle function names in the generated code (to support overloading); the C compiler will not.

Comment: @Nemo: even if you call `gcc` rather than `g++`, the C++ compiler is used anyway if the file extension says it's a C++ source.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why they chose to use g++ instead of gcc, but I believe it shouldn't matter, as any valid C program is also valid C++.

Comment: Not quite. What if your C code has a variable called `class`?

Comment: `int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)); // this is not valid C++, but is valid C`

Comment: @bdonian; That is still valid C++, however, it isn't ideal. C++ allows you to call a function called malloc, with an integral argument.

Comment: @Arafangion: This is valid C++: `void *p = malloc(sizeof(int));` but this is not: `int* x = p;`