# How to compile a c++ program in Linux?

Tags: c++

I made a file hi.cpp and I wrote the command given below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World! ";
  cout << "I'm a C++ program";
  return 0;
}
```

then I ran it in my RHEL 6 machine with the following command

```
gcc hi.cpp
```

and I got some errors which are as follows:

```
[chankey@localhost ~]$ gcc hi.cpp
/tmp/cc32bnmR.o: In function `main':
hi.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
hi.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, const char*)'
hi.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `std::cout'
hi.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, const char*)'
/tmp/cc32bnmR.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
hi.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
hi.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/cc32bnmR.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[chankey@localhost ~]$
```

What do these errors denote? My code is correct then why am I getting errors?

Comment: Good idea to add a couple of other flags when compiling. `-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` This will take warnings (logical errors in your thinking) and point them out to you.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use g++

```
g++ -o hi hi.cpp
```

g++ is for C++, gcc is for C although with the -libstdc++ you can compile c++ most people don't do this.

Comment: That's dangerous. You shouldn't call a compiled file `*.o`. That's for object files and you didn't add the `-c` flag. The binary name should be `hi` in this case, not `hi.o`.

Comment: @bitmask It's not necessarily dangerous as file extension has nothing to do with it, you can name it whatever you want.

Comment: It was, because other build systems could mistake it for a proper binary.

Answer (score 17):

As the other answers say, use **g++** instead of **gcc**.

Or use make: `make hi`

Comment: @VJo: Actually, there are default rules that will usually handle simple programs.

Comment: Cool. I tried `make hi.cpp` and that failed. `make hi` works fine

Answer (score 6):

You have to use g++ (as mentioned in other answers). On top of that you can think of providing some good options available at command line (which helps you avoid making ill formed code):

```
g++   -O4    -Wall hi.cpp -o hi.out
     ^^^^^   ^^^^^^
  optimize  related to coding mistakes
```

For more detail you can refer to `man g++ | less`.

Comment: Optimizing a "hello world" program with -O4? Really? Also `man g++` doesn't need to be piped through `less`.

Comment: @meagar, OP doesn't want to just write and stop at hello world. I suggested him to use this for future learning.

Answer (score 4):

For a simple hello-world project, calling the compiler directly with `g++` command or creating a `make` file are good options as already answered:

```
g++ -o hi hi.cpp
```

or

```
# After creating the makefile  
make hi
```

---

For serious projects, however, the usage of a project manager is required. At the time I write this answer, the most used and open-source is `cmake` (an alternative could be QT qmake ).

**Following is a simple CMake example:**

Make sure you installed `cmake` on your linux distribution `apt-get install cmake` or `yum install cmake`.

Create a file `CMakeLists.txt` (the name is important) together with your source `hi.cpp`

```
project("hi")

add_executable( hi hi.cpp )
```

Then compile and run as:

```
cmake -B <path_to_build_folder> -S <path_to_source_folder>
cmake --build <path_to_build_folder>
cd <path_to_build_folder>; ./hi
```

This allows the project to **scale** easily with libraries, sources, unit-tests, and much more. It also **makes most IDEs to understand the project** properly (Most IDEs accept CMake natively, like kdevelop, qtCreator, etc..)

[image: Example of CMake integration with Qt-Creator]

You could also generate Visual-Studio or XCode projects from CMake, in case you decide to port the software to other platforms in the future.

```
cmake -G Xcode . #will generate `hi.xcodeproj` you can load on macOS
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
g++ -o hi hi.cpp
```

gcc is only for C

Comment: gcc with libstdc++ can compile c++ but it's not recommended

Answer (score 0):

$ g++ 1st.cpp -o 1st

$ ./1st

if you found any error then first install g++ using  code as below

$ sudo apt-get install g++

then install g++ and use above run code

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ -o foo foo.cpp
```

g++  --> [Driver for cc1plus compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

-o   -->  Indicates the output file (*foo* is the name of output file here. Can be any name)

foo.cpp --> Source file to be compiled

To **execute** the compiled file simply type

```
./foo
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To Compile your C++ code use:-

> g++ file_name.cpp -o executable_file_name

(i) -o option is used to show error in the code
(ii) if there is no error in the code_file, then it will generate
an executable file.

2. Now execute the generated executable file:

> ./executable_file_name