# How do I turn on RTTI with Cygwin?

Tags: c++, cygwin, android-ndk, rtti, cocos2d-x

When my Android NDK C++ native code is compiled, the following error appears:

> error: 'dynamic_cast' not permitted with -fno-rtti

Someone told me to turn on RTTI, but I didn't know how to do. Do I need to modify `Application.mk` or what?

my `Application.mk`:

```
# it is needed for ndk-r5

APP_STL := stlport_static

APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a

APP_MODULES := cocos2d cocosdenshion chipmunk box2d tempestkeep
```

When I add `APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti`  in some .o file appears another error:

> undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::ios_base'

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to remove `-fno-rtti` gcc option in Application.mk. Look for it in `APP_CPPFLAGS` variable in Application.mk.

Comment: you need to link with libstdc++, pass `-lstdc++` to linker command line

Comment: Doesn't using the `g++` command rather than `gcc` do that automatically?

Comment: @Keith: Yes `g++` does this automatically. There are 2 options here: either use `gcc` and pass `-lstdc++` explicitly or use `g++` and `-lstdc++` will be passed implicitly.

Comment: Is that the only difference in behavior between the `gcc` and `g++` commands?  Is there any reason *not* to use `g++` when compiling C++ code?

Comment: @Keith: there are some other differences, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/173007/72178) for example. In general it is preferable to use `g++` for C++ code.