# Program "g++ not found in path" in Eclipse Juno CDT in Ubuntu

Tags: g++, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-12.04

Eclipse June CDT reports `g++ not found in path`, how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install g++?  Also, in eclipse you may have to set the compiler path in preferences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically, g++ will be installed when gcc (GNU Compiler Collection) is installed.
First confirm that you have g++ installed.

You can check this by typing the following in a terminal: which g++.
The response ought to be /usr/bin/g++.

If you find g++ installed, in eclipse go to project->properties->C/C++ Build->Discovery Options, under tools GCC C++ Compiler, put the exact path to g++ instead of g++ (if g++ alone does not work).

You will find this link useful:
[What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

If you still have problems, do get back with feedback.

Comment: version option gives me "g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"

Comment: I set "compiler invocation command" into the exact path.nothing  changes.
also,is there a fix that does fixing for all projects instead of one?

Comment: So it clear that you have g++ installed on the box.  This points to the path not being correct in eclipse.  Try adding the path variable to the evironment here: window->preferences->C/C++->build->Environment.

Comment: My problem solves after install g++, restart eclipse, build project. Eclipse Kepler, Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem and it is solved by

1. Installing g++ The GNU C++ complier using ubuntu software centre and
2. Changing in -

   Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery -> CDT GCC Build in    Complier  Settings [Shared]

   From:   ${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"

   To: /usr/bin/${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"

I hope it helps. I think if you add it to the project as mentioned in the first answer, you will need to add all the time for new projects.  And if you add as I wrote you don't need to add it for new projects.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I never had problems with eclipse before under linux and now it wont even compile code. I tried to change the name of the g++ and gcc compilers to their exact location in project->properties->c/c++ Build->discovery options etc. nothing helped, I tried to reinstall eclipse and did an initialize, added the path to the variables etc.. Nothing worked so fare. The project I am working on is quiet big and I rather would like eclipse to manage the source and makefile, instead of doing it manually

Linux Mint 15 Eclispe: Version: 3.8.1 (I tried it with the latest version as well ... nothing changed)

g++ --version g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3 Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcc --version gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3 Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

example:

```
#include // not resolved using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Well the code above is not what bothers me, as I can fix it by adding the includes of the exact c++ include path, but the code just wont compile. Wired enough eclipse gives me the error:

Description Resource Path Location Type Program "g++" not found in PATH Preferences, C++/Build/Settings/Discovery, [CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings] options C/C++ Scanner Discovery Problem

but it appears to me to be possible to compile single files, by opening them and pressing crt+b, but the whole project wont compile.

**Fixed the problem this morning:

- got the latest eclipse

- created a new workspace

- created a new project**

after a few seconds the very same error disappears

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed for me once I deleted eclipse's .metedata folder, called eclipse -initialize from the command line and started eclipse again. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new Workspace directory on Eclipse startup solved the problem for me.