# C struct creation error does not name a type

Tags: c, struct

I am just trying to set up a simple recursive struct without too much knowledge of C (have to learn somehow)

here is my make compile line

```
g++ -o cs533_hw3 main.c
```

here is my code

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{
    int texture;
    float rotation;
    Node *children[2];
};

Node rootNode;
rootNode.rotation
```

Here is my error on the last line

```
error: 'rootNode' does not name a type
```

Comment: [Don't use g++ for C code, use gcc.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Comment: +1 @Mike, except that for both `clang` or `clang++` might be even better for a beginner - for the higher quality error messages if nothing else.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Code has to be in functions in C.  You can declare variables at the global scope, but you can't put statements there.

Corrected example:

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{
    int texture;
    float rotation;
    Node *children[2];
};

Node rootNode;

int main(void)
{
    rootNode.rotation = 12.0f;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks right. But you probably wanted to do something with rootNode.rotation?

```
Node rootNode;
memset(&rootNode, 0, sizeof(rootNode)); // zero everything there
rootNode.rotation = .5f;
```