# Error in running the program in linux using g++

Tags: c++

While compiling this using g++ on linux gives an error
In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to`GradeBook::GradeBook(std::string)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am using this command to compile:

`g++ -o gradebook.cpp gradebook.h main.cpp`

```
// gradebook.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "gradebook.h"

GradeBook::GradeBook( string name )
{
 setCourseName( name );
 maximumGrade = 0;
}

void GradeBook::setCourseName( string name )
{
 if ( name.length() <= 25 )
  courseName = name;
 else 
  {
   courseName = name.substr( 0, 25 );
   cout << "Name \"" << name << "\" exceeds maximum length (25).\n"
    << "Limiting courseName to first 25 characters.\n" << endl;
  } 
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName()`
{
 return courseName;`
}

void GradeBook::displayMessage()
{
 cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!\n" << endl;
}

int maximum( int, int, int );
int maximumGrade;` 

void GradeBook::inputGrades()
{
 int grade1;
 int grade2;
 int grade3;
 cout << "Enter three integer grades: ";
 cin >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3;
}

int GradeBook::maximum( int x, int y, int z )`
{
 int maximumValue = x;
 if ( y > maximumValue )
  maximumValue = y;
 if ( z > maximumValue )
  maximumValue = z;
 return maximumValue;
}

void GradeBook::displayGradeReport()
{
 cout << "Maximum of grades entered: " <<  endl;
}
```

// gradebook.h

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GradeBook
{
 public:
  GradeBook (string);
  void setCourseName (string);
  string getCourseName ();
  void displayMessage();
  void inputGrades ();
  void displayGradeReport (); 
  int maximum (int, int, int);
 private:
  string courseName;
  int maximumGrade;
};
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "gradebook.h"

int main (int argc, char*argv[])
{
 GradeBook  myGradeBook ("Introduction to C++");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should specify the output's name after the -o flag, you forgot to do it!

Comment: Please reformat the question. You can use four spaces of indentation to create block of code

Comment: @faranwath You should make that an answer

Answer (score 3):

GCC's -o option lets you specify the executable's/library's name, as in

```
g++ -o foo.exe foo.cpp
```

You forgot to add the name after the flag, so I assume it's taking gradebook.cpp as the output's name.

In your case, it should be

```
g++ -o my_prog gradebook.cpp main.cpp
```

Comment: Can you tell me the exact command of how to compile it ? I am struggling to do it. Sorry if my question sounds very stupid.

Comment: When i use the command you told me it says my_prog directory not found. I have also created a file with the name as my_prog. How should I proceed.

Comment: Well, I've never used GCC under Linux, so I don't know how to name an "executable" there (if that concept even exists). Simply don't specify any name: g++ gradebook.cpp main.cpp

Comment: @DX delete the file my_prog you created.  The compiler will be making the output for you.  (You could leave out the `-o` option alternatively, usually gcc uses the .out extension such as `a.out` by default)

Comment: Its g++ not gcc.. gcc is for compiling c programs

Comment: @DX Yes, well... if I were at a command line I'd be typing the right one.  They are both GNU and both compilers and very related.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc

Comment: Whenever I say GCC, I'm referring to the GNU Compiler Collection, which includes gcc (a C compiler) and g++ (a C++ compiler), among others.

Comment: Thanks anyway but I can't run it.. I will try to figure out.

Comment: @DX What's the error message?  Is it still something about a directory?  (Maybe try a quick hello.cpp see that compiles)

Comment: I am following a tutorial it says that I should use the command like:    g++ -o main main.cpp gradebook.cpp   ... This will create an executable file with the name of main instead of a.out.. Now I don't know how to see the output of the code.. It should print now ... Introduction to computer programming C++