# gcc compiling C++ code: undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long long)'

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

There's a C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int b = sizeof('a');
if(b==4) printf("I'm a C program!\n");
else printf("I'm a C++ program!\n");
}
```

Compile it like this:

```
gcc main.cpp -o main
```

It succeeds and gives:

```
I'm a C++ program!
```

Then add a line somewhere inside function `main`

```
int *p1 = new int [1000];
```

It fails with:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\cccJZ8kN.o:main1.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to operator new[](unsigned long long)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then the following two commands successfully compile the code:

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -lstdc++
```

and

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

The compiler is minGW-win64 (http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/).

**The questions are:**

1. Which of the two last commands are better?
2. To my mind `gcc` correctly chooses the right compiler but then uses a wrong linker. Is it right?
3. May it be a problem in minGW-win64?

As I see (correct me if it's wrong) `gcc` was intended to be a main program that takes the input and decides what to do with it. So I'd better use `gcc` if it worked without `-lstdc++`. But if it's not possible I'll prefer using `g++` instead as don't know what else `gcc` may miss.

Many thanks for your considerations

Comment: `gcc` is for C, `g++` is for C++. `gcc -lstdc++` might work for C++, but you really should just be using `g++` for C++.

Comment: As an aside, a C++ program has `sizeof 'A' == 1`, while a C program has `sizeof 'A' == sizeof(int)`. On some implementations, both are true at the same time either way.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc

Comment: Thanks for your answers, guys! As I see it must be expected behavior of minGW-win64. Will choose `g++` for now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`gcc` is the GCC compiler-driver for C programs, `g++` is the one for C++ programs.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/172587)
Both will guess the language on the basis of the file-extension, unless overridden.

But if you use the wrong driver, the default-options will be wrong, like leaving out the C++ standard-library for C++ programs compiled with `gcc` when linking.

You *can* add just the library with `-lstdc++`, though using the proper driver is preferable, as plain gcc [may be missing other, subtler options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc#comment20333675_173007).