# The same piece of code, can compile in xcode or using g++, clang++ in terminal, cannot compile using gcc or clang. Why?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc, g++

I am using mac osx yosemite, xcode 6.1.1.
I wrote this simple piece of code. When I compile and link it with gcc, I kept getting error:
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

But the same code compiles successfully in xcode, or using g++, clang++. I wonder what is the difference?
the project is a single file contain:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    vector<ListNode *> vec;
    vec.push_back(new ListNode(0));
    vec.push_back(new ListNode(1));
    cout<<vec[0]->val<<vec[1]->val<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simply because you need c++ compiler to successfully compile c++ code?

Comment: gcc is a c++ compiler, too. it is said to evoke g++ for c++ code.

Comment: Yes, but it does not link with c++ library (unless explicitly told so). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use g++ to link the object files it automatically links in the std C++ libraries (gcc does not do this). That is why xcode, g++ and clang++ will compile your code but gcc will throw errors.

> GCC: GNU Compiler Collection
>   - Refers to all the different languages that are supported by the GNU compiler.
>
> > gcc: GNU C      Compiler
> >     g++: GNU C++ Compiler

**The main differences between `gcc` and `g++`:**

1. gcc will compile: `*.c/*.cpp` files as C and C++ respectively.
2. g++ will compile: `*.c/*.cpp` files but they will all be treated as C++ files.
   ***Also if you use g++ to link the object files it automatically links in the std C++ libraries (gcc does not do this).***
3. gcc compiling C files has less predefined macros.
4. gcc compiling `*.cpp` and g++ compiling `*.c/*.cpp` files has a few extra macros.