# __cplusplus < 201402L return true in gcc even when I specified -std=c++14

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++14, predefined-macro

The directive:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
  #error C++ is required
#elif __cplusplus < 201402L
  #error C++14 is required
#endif
```

The command-line: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -c -o header.o header.hpp`

My g++ version: `g++ (tdm-1) 4.9.2`

The error `C++14 is required` is generated even when I added `-std=c++14`, I don't know why.

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Some compilers would treat `-std=c++14` as a request to enable whatever C++14 features were implemented, while `201402L` would imply *complete* support for that standard, so it's not necessarily simply an error/bug with GCC. Go read the GCC docs if you want to understand what it's doing....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the GCC CPP manual (version [4.9.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros) and [5.1.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros)):

> **`__cplusplus`** This macro is defined when the C++ compiler is in use. You can use `__cplusplus` to test whether a header is compiled by a C compiler or a C++ compiler. This macro is similar to `__STDC_VERSION__`, in that it expands to a version number. Depending on the language standard selected, the value of the macro is `199711L`, as mandated by the 1998 C++ standard; `201103L`, per the 2011 C++ standard; **an unspecified value strictly larger than `201103L`** for the experimental languages enabled by `-std=c++1y` and `-std=gnu++1y`.

You can check that `g++ --std=c++14` defines `__cplusplus` as:

```
 Version    __cplusplus
  4.8.3       201300L
  4.9.2       201300L
  5.1.0       201402L
```

For `clang++ --std=c++14`:

```
 Version    __cplusplus
  3.3          201305L
  3.4          201305L
  3.5.x        201402L
  3.6          201402L
  3.7          201402L
```

So a safer check should probably be:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#  error C++ is required
#elif __cplusplus <= 201103L
#  error C++14 is required
#endif
```

As specified in the comment, this could mean partial C++14 support.

To check for a specific feature you could also try [Boost Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) (especially [Macros that describe C++14 features not supported](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__14_features_not_supported)).

Comment: Does the `__cplusplus` macro gets set when the extension of the file is `.cpp` or when the program is compiled using a compiler. Because when I wrote a simple program using the above information and compiled the program using `gcc` rather than `g++`, the compiler aborts the compilation but on the basis of `#elif` and if I don't write the `#elif` condition and compile the program using `gcc` it doesn't abort according to the condition `#ifndef __cplusplus` Can you clarify about what is actually happening? Code Reference: https://pastebin.com/iiuzPrwW

Comment: @strikersps The `__cplusplus` preprocessor macro is defined if the compilation unit is compiled with a C++ compiler. Technically, either `gcc` or `g++` can be used for general C++ development with applicable option settings. However, the `g++` default behavior is naturally aligned to a C++ development. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/172587/3235496 for further details.