# Rcpp appears to be using incorrect g++ flag despite makevars

Tags: c++, rcpp

I'm working on a linux box, with the Makevars file I created in ~/.R/Makevars containing the following:

```
CXX = g++
CXXSTD = -std=gnu++17
```

I am running R 3.5.1-intel-mkl with the following code:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
sourceCpp("code.cpp",cacheDir="~/goldfish/solvers/junkdir",rebuild=T,showOutput=T,verbose=T)
```

I doubt the contents of the cpp file is important as the error is referring to environmental issues:

```
code.cpp: In function ‘void polyRegression(const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’:
code.cpp:188:18: error: ‘transform_reduce’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

I tried this line of code (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980383/how-to-determine-what-c-standard-is-the-default-for-a-c-compiler/46980534))

```
g++ -x c++  -E -dM -< /dev/null | grep __cplusplus
```

to test for the version and this was the output:

```
#define __cplusplus 201402L
```

Which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995705/cplusplus-201402l-return-true-in-gcc-even-when-i-specified-std-c14) may mean partial support. I'm a bit lost, so my questions are:

**1) Is the transform_reduce method not supported in this version of g++? If not, can you recommend any alternatives?
2) If transform_reduce IS supported and I have an error in my Makevars, or the OS isn't picking it up for some reason, how do I force the OS to find it?**

EDIT:

Following advice from Dirk Eddelbuettel (thanks again) I need to set all the correct variables and flags in the Makevars. I've read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597632/understanding-the-contents-of-the-makevars-file-in-r-macros-variables-r-ma), too, which was enlightening, but I'm unsure what to set for C++ to compile to a version for transform_reduce to function. Here are my flags at the moment (I thought `CXXSTD` and `CXX17STD` would solve the issue, but it hasn't).

```
CXX = g++
CXXSTD = -std=gnu++17
CXXCPP = $(CXX) -E
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 $(LTO)
CXXPICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX98 = g++
CXX98FLAGS = -g -O2
CXX98PICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX98STD = -std=gnu++98
CXX11 = g++
CXX11FLAGS = -g -O2
CXX11PICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX11STD = -std=gnu++11
CXX14 = g++
CXX14FLAGS = -g -O2
CXX14PICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX14STD = -std=gnu++14
CXX17 = g++
CXX17FLAGS = -g -O2
CXX17PICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX17STD = -std=gnu++17
```

Comment: Do a quick grep or look in editor at R's own `Makeconf`, i.e. `R.home("etc/Makeconf")`. `CXX` may not be the only compiler set.  Also see https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-and-c++11-c++14-c++17/ for a worked solution.

Comment: Ah that's interesting - thank you! I had a look, and this may be the culprit: `CXX1XSTD = -std=gnu++11`. The issue is, I'm working on a shared high-powered computing server, I can't make edits to this Makevars. I was assured the local file would take precedence. So I'm still unsure where the problem is coming from - is there a test in-code that can output which Makevars is being used?

Comment: You are on the right track. Your own `~/.R/Makeconf` takes precedence _but you have to set all the right variables_.  So these days I have `CXXFLAGS` as well as `CXX{{1X,11,14,17}FLAGS` in mine (and I think only the `1X` one is redundant now).

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel - rather than squeeze my response here I edited the question. See the EDIT at the bottom - thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: Update: I had the same issue on my OSX, setting these in my `Makeconf` file sorted it there: `CXX11STD = -std=gnu++17` and `CXX = clang++ -std=gnu++17`. Of course that's OSX instead of Linux, and using clang. So I tried doing similar on the server (set all flags to `-std=gnu++17`) but same error, although now do see in the output of `sourcecpp` that it is indeed using `g++ -std=gnu++17`. Weird that it's using the right compiler but the issue is still present.

Comment: I am sorry that you still have to work this out but nobody can help with a [minimally complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).