# "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER broken" while compiling with CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake

I'm trying to compile a Git project, and I'm facing some problems with CMake. Initially, it didn't find the C++ compiler and prompted an error:

```
cmake ..
```

> No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
>
> Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

So, I did:

```
CXX="gcc" cmake ..
```

But another error was prompted:

> -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- broken
>   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
>       The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

How can I solve this error and compile the project?

Comment: Are you trying to use CMake on a Linux or Mac OS system? CMake should be able to detect the default compiler on your machine automatically. What does `g++ -v` command returns in a terminal?

Comment: Linux system. About the `g++ -v`, it throws a "command not found".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are trying to use *C* compiler `gcc` as *C++* one, which is wrong.

You need to install `g++` or other *C++* compiler.

Comment: Really? I read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/173007/3029543) and, in my understanding, it says that the gcc can compile both C and C++ programs.

Comment: It can, but it requires at least stdc++ library, which comes with g++. Just install g++, and everything will work without intervention like setting CXX variable.

Answer (score 52):

You should try installing `build-essential` if you haven't done so.

Try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. But why? What does the `build-essential` package do?

Comment: I ended up doing: `sudo apt purge gcc-7 gcc-8 gcc-9 gcc-10 gcc c-compiler && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt install gcc-9 g++-9 gcc g++ build-essential` and that fixed my issue (which was `No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found. Tell CMake where,compiler name if it is in the PATH.`)

Comment: this works, but it's a bad answer because it doesn't explain why it works

Comment: build-essential worked for me also. Looks like build-essential is a package that contains a list of required Debian packages as dependencies, so when you install build-essential, you install all those packages in one single command.