# compiling .cpp with gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

**okay this I did accidentally , compiling .cpp using gcc and not g++**

but I actually want to understand the console output, line by line, if it has any sense.

```
struct a{
   int pointer;
   int  rollno;
};

struct a student,*studentref;
studentref = &student;
studentref->rollno = 141; 
studentref->pointer = 8;

cout<<studentref->rollno<<") : "<<studentref->pointer<<endl;
```

compiling this code with `gcc structpointers.cpp -o structp` gives the following output:

```
sourab@sourab:/home/gbear/coding/learningds$ gcc structpointers.cpp -o structp
/tmp/ccXrq1Cv.o: In function `main':
structpointers.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `std::cout'
structpointers.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
structpointers.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
structpointers.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/ccXrq1Cv.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
structpointers.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
structpointers.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Your question should be "linking c++ program with gcc", compiling .cpp by gcc pretty fine - gcc determines mode by file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most egregious difference between calling `g++` and `gcc` on a `.cpp` file is that `g++` automatically links in the C++ standard library, while `gcc` does not; all the errors you see are linker errors of missing references to stuff that is provided by the C++ standard library.

(notice that this isn't the *only* difference; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/173007/214671) for details)

Answer (score 0):

g++ and gcc are compiler drivers of  GNU compiler collection, they have backends which are connected automatically once compilation mode in up.
The errors like "

```
structpointers.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `std::cout'
```

are link errors,since you have used gcc to compile cpp,the standard libraries specifically for cpp are not present, so it could not find syntax like std::cout etc.

you can also  refer to : [compiling with g++](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/howto/g++compiling.txt)