# static_cast fail to cast the address of vector

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

```
vector<vector<int>> v;
vector<int> v0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    v.push_back(v0);
}
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    cout << static_cast<void const *>(&(v[i])) << endl;
}
```

I try to treat vector as an object and cout its address like above but failed, then how can I cout the vector's address.

Comment: The linker error message does not seem to have any relationship with the title of your question.

Comment: Give us an [MCVE] please.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Well, there is [an overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) see (7), and it should match the static cast.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Quite right!  Thanks for pointing that out, I'll remove my comment.

Comment: You are right, the error message is misleading, I modified my question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `gcc`, you might want to try to compile your code with

```
g++ -std=c++14
```

Then it should work: https://ideone.com/y0DwdA.

The linker error, which I could reproduce by using gcc, is most probably related to the differences between the compilers described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/172592/4770166).

---

As pointed out by @πάνταῥεῖ, the compiler flag `-std=c++11` will work as well.

Comment: I can't see any relevance for `-std=c++14 ` here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you insert a space betwen `>>` in the first line, at the end of the nested vector declaration, there is none.

Comment: `-std==c++11` or no specific flag will solve this already, unless an older `cx03` compiler is used.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree that -std=c++11 is sufficient, but no complier flag won't work, at least not generally. I'm using g++ version 5.2.1 and the >> is a syntax error without the mentioned flags.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall main.cc` the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<vector<int>> v;
    vector<int> v0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        v.push_back(v0);
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        cout << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&(v[i])) << endl;
    }
}
```