# gcc main.cpp -o main.out not working

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

when I run: 'gcc getline.cpp -o main.out' it fails and gives a really long error message. The program compiles and runs with 'make getline' then './getline'. I'm fairly certain that i have gcc installed because when i just type gcc it gives me the error message 'clang: error:no input files'. Also for reference I'm running OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 although I don't think that is playing a factor. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 int main ()
{
  std::string mystr;
  std::cout << "What's your name? ";
  std::getline (cin, mystr);
  std::cout << "Hello " << mystr << ".\n";
  std::cout << "What is your favorite team? ";
  std::getline (std::cin, mystr);
  std::cout << "I like " << mystr << " too!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error message that prints out:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      _main in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      _main in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      _main in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::cin", referenced from:
      _main in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      _main in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      _main in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in getline-5b273e.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
      std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::getline<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, char) in getline-5b273e.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in getline-5b273e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Use `g++`, not `gcc`.

Comment: Compile it with `g++`. `gcc` doesn't link in the C++ standard library by default, see [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/172587/1942027). Also your first `getline` is missing `std::` for cin.

Comment: You need to fix `std::getline (cin, mystr);` to `std::getline (std::cin, mystr);`.

Comment: After correcting the issue, the program compiles with `g++` and runs.

Comment: yeah I actually had the std::cin correct in my original code, but messed it up here somehow. Thank you.

Comment: use of `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to install g++