# std::call_once() hangs on second call after callable threw on first call

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, libstdc++, compiler-bug

Given this piece of code:

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

void f(bool doThrow) {
    if (doThrow) {
        std::cout << "Throwing" << std::endl;
        throw 42;
    }
    std::cout << "Not throwing" << std::endl;
}

std::once_flag flag;

void g(bool doThrow) {
    try {
        std::call_once(flag, f, doThrow);
        std::cout << "Returning" << std::endl;
    } catch (int i) {
        std::cout << "Caught " << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::once_flag flag;
    g(true);
    g(true);
    g(false);
    g(true);
    g(false);
}
```

When compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -ggdb` I get the output:

```
Throwing
Caught 42
```

after which the process hangs:

```
#0  0x000003fff7277abf in futex_wait (private=0, expected=1, futex_word=0x2aaaacad144 <flag>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:61
#1  futex_wait_simple (private=0, expected=1, futex_word=0x2aaaacad144 <flag>) at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:135
#2  __pthread_once_slow (once_control=0x2aaaacad144 <flag>, init_routine=0x3fff7a8d870 <std::__once_proxy()>) at pthread_once.c:105
#3  0x000002aaaaaab06f in __gthread_once (__once=0x2aaaacad144 <flag>, __func=0x3fff7a8d870 <std::__once_proxy()>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:699
#4  0x000002aaaaaab6c8 in std::call_once<void (&)(bool), bool&> (__once=..., __f=@0x2aaaaaab08c: {void (bool)} 0x2aaaaaab08c <f(bool)>) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/mutex:738
#5  0x000002aaaaaab192 in g (doThrow=true) at test.cpp:17
#6  0x000002aaaaaab287 in main () at test.cpp:27
```

But when compiled with `clang++ -std=c++11 -pthread -ggdb` I get:

```
Throwing
Caught 42
Throwing
Caught 42
Not throwing
Returning
Returning
Returning
```

As far as I know this seems to be the correct behavior.

Is this a GCC bug, just me being confused over the semantics of `std::call_once`, or is my code incorrect?

Comment: Replicated, seems like a bug.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス so what? One is a part of the other.

Comment: @user2079303 Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Comment: gcc 6.3.1 doesn't hang, but bails out: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
`

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス so, you referred to the compiler driver by "`gcc`"? How is that relevant to this question then? It is not mentioned once.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス This is about GCC (as in the [GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/)), not `gcc`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think you are missing `-pthread` when compiling. See GCC [PR 55394](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55394).

Comment: Yeah, that was it.

Comment: I did not know that every compiler driver has a tag in SO. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス actually, all compiler drivers do not have a tag. gcc in particuar does not have, because gcc tag is used for the gnu compiler collection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in the GNU C++ Library.

---

Surely this is a bug since even the default `std::call_once` [example from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) will hang if you try to use the provided online compiler (Coliru) :)

The bug happens in g++ linux implementation which uses pthreads. What puzzled me is that [this Wandbox example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PdcKWT0slTxeom2j) runs just fine. I checked the versions of `libstdc++`:

- Wandbox: `GLIBCXX: 20130411`
- Coliru: `GLIBCXX: 20161221`

Therefore I believe it is a `libstdc++` bug, probably [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70298), or more precisely [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66146).

Comment: `This has nothing to do with libstdc++, the std::call_once code is identical on x86 and ppc, and you get the same behaviour with pthreads, so it should be reported to glibc instead`, from [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66146#c1).