# how to implement scoped enum in C

Tags: c, enums

In C++ you can do this

```
enum class Colors {black, blue, green, cyan, red, purple, yellow, white};
Colors mycolor;

mycolor = Colors::blue; // this is what I want to do
```

In `C`, is it possible to refer to an enum using `EnumName::tag`?

Comment: That *would be* a useful feature...

Comment: namespaces are a c++ thing and ````::```` is an operator for resolving namespaces.

Comment: If you find that there are *several* C++ features that would improve your C code, there is a way to fix this. A bit Blasphemous, probably, but still possible.  :-)  [gcc vs g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In C, is it possible to refer to an enum using EnumName::tag?

No, it is not. Read C11 standard, e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft (§6.7.2.2)

In practice, C programmers have a lot of *conventions*, such as using some common prefix for all the tags in some `enum`.

For example in [GTK](http://gtk.org/) all the tags of [`enum GtkShadowType`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkShadowType) start with `GTK_SHADOW_` (a common prefix, by *human  convention*), like `GTK_SHADOW_IN` and `GTK_SHADOW_OUT`. This makes the C code more readable for developers, since [GTK](http://gtk.org/) has a *lot* of `enum`s.

In some cases, **you may *generate* C code** (with software like [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or your own one). Then your C code generator should also document and adopt such naming conventions for generated C code (in particular, to help the human developer recognize easily generated C names from hand-written ones).

In large software (e.g. the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/)), **it is important to *document* naming and coding conventions**. This facilitates the job of future developers.

**Good source code editors** (e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) **can be configured to type long identifiers with *few* key presses**, and current C optimizing compilers spend much more time in optimization than in parsing, so after 2020 having long but readable identifiers is important in large software code bases (and that does not impact significantly the compilation time, or the runtime).

Don't forget that with care, you can mix C and C++ code, and make a library coded in C++ which has a C interface and API. The [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) is a good example (with it, you can embed an optimizing [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler -it is coded in C++- in your application, which would construct some abstract syntax tree). Be careful about C++ exceptions: all of them should be caught before returning from your library.

Comment: What is the point of the trailing underscore?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili It's "trailing" only in the prefix, so `GTK_SHADOW_FOO` instead of `GTK_SHADOWFOO`.