# trouble compiling code that includes string

Tags: c++

**I have a simple bit of code which is having trouble compiling.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  string hello = "Hello World";
  printf("%s\n",hello.c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

**compiling with "gcc test.cpp -o test"
returns the following message.**

/tmp/ccgbRaOf.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to`std::allocator::allocator()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to`std::allocator::~allocator()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const'
test.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to`std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
test.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to`std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
/tmp/ccgbRaOf.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
test.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccgbRaOf.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc

Answer (score 1):

You compile it with `gcc` which is for C, but your code is C++. Use `g++`.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you are using a C compiler. For C++ you need a different compiler. Try with `g++`