# Advantage to use gfortran over gcc

Tags: gcc, gnu, gfortran

Venturing out the `bash` profile in https://repl.it/, their installation includes *both* `gcc` as well as `gfortran`:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
[...]
gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
[...]
```

I have no difficulty to compile a code compliant to Fortran95 with either one of the two.  Yet, as  `gfortran` is part of `gcc` ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Fortran)), where are functional advantages to use either the specialist (`gfortran`), or the collection (`gcc`)?

Comment: I had no idea fortran could be compiled with gcc.

Comment: Note that both `gcc` and `gfortran` are parts of GCC (GNU compiler collection). For `gcc` to be able to compile Fortran the Fortran frontend must be installed in the GCC installation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc?rq=1

Comment: @orangecaterpillar The opposite here; only because a .f95 shall be used in pure Windows instead of Debian, I learnt about g95 and gfortran ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the [GNU Fortran manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GNU-Fortran-and-GCC.html):

> A `gfortran` driver program is also provided, which is identical to `gcc` except that it automatically links the Fortran runtime libraries into the compiled program.

If your program does not depend on the Fortran run-time library, then you can link it successfully using `gcc`.  The situation is similar to that of C++ and `g++`, except that C++ run-time library dependencies are perhaps more common.