# Passing an SDL_Window* struct to a function using address of in C

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

My goal here is to make creating new mini windows or just separate windows take less code.
Instead of:

```
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", 
                                      SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                                      SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                      h, w,
                                      flags);
```

It would be more like:

```
SDL_Window* message_box;
createMessageBox(&message_box, "Message Box");
```

with the function createMessageBox:

```
void createMessageBox(SDL_Window* message_box, char title[10]) {
    const int MESS_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 240;
    const int MESS_WINDOW_LENGTH = 180;
    
    Uint32 message_box_flags = SDL_WINDOW_SKIP_TASKBAR | SDL_WINDOW_ALWAYS_ON_TOP;
    message_box = SDL_CreateWindow(title, 
                                   SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                   SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                   MESS_WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                                   MESS_WINDOW_LENGTH,
                                   message_box_flags);
}
```

But my problem is I get an error:

```
error: cannot convert SDL_Window** to SDL_Window*
createMessageBox(&message_box, "Message Box");
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have zero idea about what the compiler is talking about here.
What is `SDL_Window**`. I tried looking around online but couldn't find anything about it.

As far as I'm concerned this should work?

Full error:

```
g++ main.c -w -lSDL2 -o test
main.c: In function int main():
main.c:64:19: error: cannot convert SDL_Window** to SDL_Window*
    createMessageBox(&message_box, "Message Box");
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:12:35: note:   initializing argument 1 of void createMessageBox(SDL_Window*, char*)
    void createMessageBox(SDL_Window* message_box, char title[10]) {
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:19: all] Error 1
```

**p.s I already know about SDL_ShowMessageBox that's not really what I'm looking for.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable of type `SDL_Window*` by reference to the function `createMessageBox`, then you must pass a pointer to that pointer, i.e. you must pass a parameter of type `SDL_Window**`. So you should change the function parameters

```
void createMessageBox(SDL_Window* message_box, char title[10])
```

to:

```
void createMessageBox(SDL_Window** message_box, char title[10])
```

Now, you can change the line

```
message_box = SDL_CreateWindow(title, [...]
```

to:

```
*message_box = SDL_CreateWindow(title, [...]
```

This will write the return value of `SDL_CreateWindow` directly into the pointed-to variable in the calling function.

See these links for a tutorial on the difference between call by value and call by reference:

- [Call by Value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm)
- [Call by Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm)

Comment: @callcj: Note that this answer applies to the language C, not C++, because you tagged the question with that language. However, I noticed that you are using a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. An answer for the language C++ would be a bit more complex, as there would also be a different solution. If you want an answer for the language C++, then please remove the `c` tag in your question and replace it with a `c++` tag.

Comment: @callcj: If you want to use the language C and not C++, then you should probably invoke your compiler with `gcc` instead of `g++`. See this question for further information: [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/172587/12149471)