# Generic "was not declared in this scope" error in standard C++ library headers

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, std

Recently I stumbled into a multiple "was not declared in this scope" error looking like this:

```sh
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/string_conversions.h:84:25: error: ‘ERANGE’ was not declared in this scope
   84 |       else if (errno == ERANGE
      |                         ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/system_error:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from myproject/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:42:40: error: ‘EAFNOSUPPORT’ was not declared in this scope
   42 |       address_family_not_supported =   EAFNOSUPPORT,
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:43:28: error: ‘EADDRINUSE’ was not declared in this scope
   43 |       address_in_use =     EADDRINUSE,
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:44:34: error: ‘EADDRNOTAVAIL’ was not declared in this scope
   44 |       address_not_available =    EADDRNOTAVAIL,
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:45:30: error: ‘EISCONN’ was not declared in this scope
   45 |       already_connected =    EISCONN,
      |                              ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:46:35: error: ‘E2BIG’ was not declared in this scope
   46 |       argument_list_too_long =    E2BIG,
      |                                   ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:47:35: error: ‘EDOM’ was not declared in this scope
   47 |       argument_out_of_domain =    EDOM,
      |                                   ^~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:48:25: error: ‘EFAULT’ was not declared in this scope
   48 |       bad_address =     EFAULT,
      |                         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:49:32: error: ‘EBADF’ was not declared in this scope
   49 |       bad_file_descriptor =    EBADF,
      |                                ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:52:25: error: ‘EBADMSG’ was not declared in this scope
   52 |       bad_message =     EBADMSG,
      |                         ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:55:25: error: ‘EPIPE’ was not declared in this scope
   55 |       broken_pipe =     EPIPE,
      |                         ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:56:31: error: ‘ECONNABORTED’ was not declared in this scope
   56 |       connection_aborted =    ECONNABORTED,
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:57:42: error: ‘EALREADY’ was not declared in this scope
   57 |       connection_already_in_progress =   EALREADY,
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:58:31: error: ‘ECONNREFUSED’ was not declared in this scope
   58 |       connection_refused =    ECONNREFUSED,
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:59:29: error: ‘ECONNRESET’ was not declared in this scope
   59 |       connection_reset =    ECONNRESET,
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:60:30: error: ‘EXDEV’ was not declared in this scope
   60 |       cross_device_link =    EXDEV,
      |                              ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:61:40: error: ‘EDESTADDRREQ’ was not declared in this scope
   61 |       destination_address_required =   EDESTADDRREQ,
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:62:35: error: ‘EBUSY’ was not declared in this scope
   62 |       device_or_resource_busy =   EBUSY,
      |                                   ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:63:32: error: ‘ENOTEMPTY’ was not declared in this scope
   63 |       directory_not_empty =    ENOTEMPTY,
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:64:35: error: ‘ENOEXEC’ was not declared in this scope
   64 |       executable_format_error =   ENOEXEC,
      |                                   ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:65:32: error: ‘EEXIST’ was not declared in this scope
   65 |       file_exists =            EEXIST,
      |                                ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:66:28: error: ‘EFBIG’ was not declared in this scope
   66 |       file_too_large =     EFBIG,
      |                            ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:67:30: error: ‘ENAMETOOLONG’ was not declared in this scope
   67 |       filename_too_long =    ENAMETOOLONG,
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:68:35: error: ‘ENOSYS’ was not declared in this scope
   68 |       function_not_supported =    ENOSYS,
      |                                   ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:69:29: error: ‘EHOSTUNREACH’ was not declared in this scope
   69 |       host_unreachable =    EHOSTUNREACH,
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:72:31: error: ‘EIDRM’ was not declared in this scope
   72 |       identifier_removed =    EIDRM,
      |                               ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:75:34: error: ‘EILSEQ’ was not declared in this scope
   75 |       illegal_byte_sequence =    EILSEQ,
      |                                  ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:76:45: error: ‘ENOTTY’ was not declared in this scope
   76 |       inappropriate_io_control_operation =  ENOTTY,
      |                                             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:77:25: error: ‘EINTR’ was not declared in this scope
   77 |       interrupted =     EINTR,
      |                         ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:79:26: error: ‘ESPIPE’ was not declared in this scope
   79 |       invalid_seek =     ESPIPE,
      |                          ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:80:22: error: ‘EIO’ was not declared in this scope
   80 |       io_error =     EIO,
      |                      ^~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:81:28: error: ‘EISDIR’ was not declared in this scope
   81 |       is_a_directory =     EISDIR,
      |                            ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:82:26: error: ‘EMSGSIZE’ was not declared in this scope
   82 |       message_size =     EMSGSIZE,
      |                          ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:83:26: error: ‘ENETDOWN’ was not declared in this scope
   83 |       network_down =     ENETDOWN,
      |                          ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:84:27: error: ‘ENETRESET’ was not declared in this scope
   84 |       network_reset =     ENETRESET,
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:85:32: error: ‘ENETUNREACH’ was not declared in this scope
   85 |       network_unreachable =    ENETUNREACH,
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:86:28: error: ‘ENOBUFS’ was not declared in this scope
   86 |       no_buffer_space =    ENOBUFS,
      |                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:87:29: error: ‘ECHILD’ was not declared in this scope
   87 |       no_child_process =    ECHILD,
      |                             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:90:21: error: ‘ENOLINK’ was not declared in this scope
   90 |       no_link =     ENOLINK,
      |                     ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:93:30: error: ‘ENOLCK’ was not declared in this scope
   93 |       no_lock_available =    ENOLCK,
      |                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:96:33: error: ‘ENODATA’ was not declared in this scope
   96 |       no_message_available =    ENODATA,
      |                                 ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:99:24: error: ‘ENOMSG’ was not declared in this scope
   99 |       no_message =     ENOMSG,
      |                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:100:31: error: ‘ENOPROTOOPT’ was not declared in this scope
  100 |       no_protocol_option =    ENOPROTOOPT,
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:101:31: error: ‘ENOSPC’ was not declared in this scope
  101 |       no_space_on_device =    ENOSPC,
      |                               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:104:32: error: ‘ENOSR’ was not declared in this scope
  104 |       no_stream_resources =    ENOSR,
      |                                ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:107:37: error: ‘ENXIO’ was not declared in this scope
  107 |       no_such_device_or_address =   ENXIO,
      |                                     ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:108:28: error: ‘ENODEV’ was not declared in this scope
  108 |       no_such_device =     ENODEV,
      |                            ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:109:37: error: ‘ENOENT’ was not declared in this scope
  109 |       no_such_file_or_directory =   ENOENT,
      |                                     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:110:28: error: ‘ESRCH’ was not declared in this scope
  110 |       no_such_process =    ESRCH,
      |                            ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:111:28: error: ‘ENOTDIR’ was not declared in this scope
  111 |       not_a_directory =    ENOTDIR,
      |                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:112:26: error: ‘ENOTSOCK’ was not declared in this scope
  112 |       not_a_socket =     ENOTSOCK,
      |                          ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:115:26: error: ‘ENOSTR’ was not declared in this scope
  115 |       not_a_stream =     ENOSTR,
      |                          ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:118:27: error: ‘ENOTCONN’ was not declared in this scope
  118 |       not_connected =     ENOTCONN,
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:119:30: error: ‘ENOMEM’ was not declared in this scope
  119 |       not_enough_memory =    ENOMEM,
      |                              ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/errno.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/cerrno:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6493,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from myproject/main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:122:27: error: ‘EOPNOTSUPP’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘ENOTSUP’?
  122 |       not_supported =     ENOTSUP,
      |                           ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/system_error:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from Pyfhel/Afhel/Afseal.cpp:34:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:129:34: error: ‘EINPROGRESS’ was not declared in this scope
  129 |       operation_in_progress =    EINPROGRESS,
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:130:35: error: ‘EPERM’ was not declared in this scope
  130 |       operation_not_permitted =   EPERM,
      |                                   ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:131:35: error: ‘EOPNOTSUPP’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘ENOTSUP’?
  131 |       operation_not_supported =   EOPNOTSUPP,
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                   ENOTSUP
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:132:34: error: ‘EWOULDBLOCK’ was not declared in this scope
  132 |       operation_would_block =    EWOULDBLOCK,
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:138:30: error: ‘EACCES’ was not declared in this scope
  138 |       permission_denied =    EACCES,
      |                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:141:28: error: ‘EPROTO’ was not declared in this scope
  141 |       protocol_error =     EPROTO,
      |                            ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:144:35: error: ‘EPROTONOSUPPORT’ was not declared in this scope
  144 |       protocol_not_supported =    EPROTONOSUPPORT,
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:145:34: error: ‘EROFS’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘EOF’?
  145 |       read_only_file_system =    EROFS,
      |                                  ^~~~~
      |                                  EOF
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:146:41: error: ‘EDEADLK’ was not declared in this scope
  146 |       resource_deadlock_would_occur =   EDEADLK,
      |                                         ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:147:42: error: ‘EAGAIN’ was not declared in this scope
  147 |       resource_unavailable_try_again =   EAGAIN,
      |                                          ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:148:32: error: ‘ERANGE’ was not declared in this scope
  148 |       result_out_of_range =    ERANGE,
      |                                ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:155:28: error: ‘ETIME’ was not declared in this scope
  155 |       stream_timeout =     ETIME,
      |                            ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:159:28: error: ‘ETXTBSY’ was not declared in this scope
  159 |       text_file_busy =     ETXTBSY,
      |                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:162:23: error: ‘ETIMEDOUT’ was not declared in this scope
  162 |       timed_out =     ETIMEDOUT,
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:163:41: error: ‘ENFILE’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean FILE’?
  163 |       too_many_files_open_in_system =   ENFILE,
      |                                         ^~~~~~
      |                                         FILE
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:164:32: error: ‘EMFILE’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean FILE’?
  164 |       too_many_files_open =    EMFILE,
      |                                ^~~~~~
      |                                FILE
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:165:28: error: ‘EMLINK’ was not declared in this scope
  165 |       too_many_links =     EMLINK,
      |                            ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:166:41: error: ‘ELOOP’ was not declared in this scope
  166 |       too_many_symbolic_link_levels =   ELOOP,
      |                                         ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:169:28: error: ‘EOVERFLOW’ was not declared in this scope
  169 |       value_too_large =    EOVERFLOW,
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/error_constants.h:172:32: error: ‘EPROTOTYPE’ was not declared in this scope
  172 |       wrong_protocol_type =    EPROTOTYPE
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from myproject/main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/thread: In function ‘void std::this_thread::sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep1, _Period1>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:378:53: error: ‘EINTR’ was not declared in this scope
  378 |  while (::nanosleep(&__ts, &__ts) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
      |                                                     ^~~~~
```

arising from a single `.cpp` compilation:

```sh
gcc -Imyproject/include1 -Imyproject/include2 -Imyproject/include3 -c myproject/main.cpp -o myproject/main.o
```

The `.cpp` file is not doing anything special:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream> /* Print in std::cout */
#include <fstream>      /* file management */
#include <thread>   /* memory pools, multithread*/
#include "myheader1.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Have " << argc << " arguments:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the `myheader.h` is **empty**.

What is the cause of this error and how to solve it?

*Note: All the error lines thrown belong to issues in the **standard library***, and switching to `g++` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: If anyone wanders why I posted this and answered it, I googled these precise errors and didn't find anything. After solving it, I thought it would be of help to index the full error messages with a minimalistic example to help others in need of this guidance.

Comment: Does this still happen if you compile with `g++` instead of `gcc`?

Comment: Yeap, [`g++` is just `gcc` with some extra parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc), and it yields the same results.

Comment: I know that, but whether those _extra parameters_ change the result is relevant information that should be in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are quite certain we didn't touch the standard library in purpose, and it is not a matter of C++ version (already tried adding `-std=c++17` and similar to the compilation args, to no avail), this error means we accidentally mangled with the standard `.h` headers.

##### What is the cause of this error?

At least one of the header files present in the `include` dirs (`myproject/include1`, `myproject/include2`, `myproject/include3` in this case) is overloading the name of a C++ stdlib module, causing it to break.

##### How to solve it?

Remove the conflicting header file (if you detect it), rename all header files in your include dirs to have non-standard names (avoid `vector.h`, `memory.h` and the sorts), or include only the files & directories needed for your compilation, leaving out the conflicting files.

Comment: I have a similar error when trying to compile my project on RHEL 8, I searched /usr/include for 'ERANGE' and it does not return any result.

Comment: @sham1810 I would check two things: 1) The compiler and its directives support C++17 or whichever version you were working with that included `ERANGE`, 2) None of the include directories you added in the compilation contains any header that could overlap with headers from the standard library.