# What is the difference between compiling a C++ file with the 'gcc' and 'c++' commands?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ubuntu-20.04

While learning C++, I tried to compile a HelloWorld program using the 'gcc' command' and found that I needed to add the '-lstdc++' option for it to compile successfully:

```
gcc HelloWorld.cpp -lstdc++
```

However, I idly tried to use 'c++' as a command to compile a file, and much to my surprise, it worked without me needing to use the -lstdc++ option, and it produced an output executable file that ran just as well as the one produced by the 'gcc' command with the '-lstdc++' option:

```
c++ HelloWorld.cpp
```

Does anyone know if there are any hidden differences in output between the two commands, and if the 'c++' command may be safely used in place of the 'gcc' command? I have searched a dozen or so websites, and not a single one of them had any documentation or samples for code featuring 'c++' used as a command to compile a C++ executable file in the OS that I'm running (Linux Ubuntu 20.04).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c++` is a soft link of `g++`.

Then you can find the difference at this question:[What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Comment: Thanks, I verified your answer was right from one of the links provided in the answer you mentioned:
how g++ is invoked (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html)

'On many systems, g++ is also installed with the name c++'

Answer (score 1):

Both commands are a part of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC), among others

- `c++` defaults to assume C++ code as an input source and should be the preferred way to compile C++ code
- `gcc` has traditionally been assumed to be a C compiler by default

Either one can compile C/C++ with appropriate options as you have found out or a mix of the sources. `-lstdc++` option exists for C, so when you have parts of the code written in C and parts in C++ to compile with `gcc`.

It is certainly safe to use `c++` for C++ projects. A [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) (`man c++`) is always a helpful resource to consult.