# Compiling a C plus plus program using GCC compiler

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I am trying to compile this little program in file `demo.cpp` by `gcc demo.cpp`,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

It does not do so successfully. I get `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:`,

This seems like pretty popular error but people are getting it on way more complicated programs. Note that *it works if I comment the cout line*. I am not sure exactly what am I doing wrong here. `gcc -v` returns,

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Use `g++` to compile c++ code. [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Comment: I was reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_getstarted.asp), "A compiler, like GCC, to translate the C++ code into a language that the computer will understand." Could you explain a little if `g++` is still called a "GCC" compiler?

Comment: @scribe: Read the link and you'd have known. It's the same compiler, just with different implicit switches (with `g++` switches being the defaults you want to compile C++ code).

Comment: Better to use clang++.

Comment: GCC is a generic term for the 'GNU Compiler Collection', the gcc command uses the GCC c compiler, g++ uses the GCC c++ compiler, gfortran invokes the GCC fortran compiler....

Comment: @ShadowRanger, the link was added as an edit after I'd already commented. I did read it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is probably because the GCC compiler, according to my experience, is supposed to compile C language codes only, not C++. G++ is used to compile C++. The specific problem with the cout line is that C uses printf(), not cout, to print to the terminal. Therefore, the C compiler outputs your line as undefined symbols.