# Problems with Quickfix list

Tags: vim, configuration, zsh, text-editor

I am trying to make `makeprg` so that when I write `:make` it will compile my c program and if there are problems put them in Quickfix list and if there are non run the program and put output to Quick fix list

I am using

- vim 9.0
- zsh
- g++ compiler on m1 mac
- in alacrity emulator

this works but it doesn't execute the code:

```
set makeprg=g++\ -w\ -g\ %\ -o\ %:r
```

when I try this one:

```
CompilerSet makeprg=rm\ -fr\ %:r;g++\ -w\ -g\ %\ -o\ %:r&&./%:r
```

it goes like this:

(I have errors in my code) it shows me the errors then I hit enter I get blank screen with :

```
E40: Can't open error file /var/folders/hc/y4sccdy52y34th77l1lc0j_c0000gn/T/vTqwygm/3
```

(last three folders change every run)

then I hit another enter return to vim and contents of Quickfix list is unchanged.

when I remove the error:

output of `./%:r` is shown with no problems.

I added :

```
rm\ -fr\ %:r
```

because I thought that if there will be no executable to run for `./%:r` it will not show in Quick fix

without that it always shows output of

```
rm\ -fr\ %:r
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: BTW, why are you compiling C with the C++ compiler `g++` instead of using `gcc`?

Comment: I don't know is there any diference? or reason to use gcc? if so could you send me some article or video?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim is redirecting the output from `makeprg` to a file, hence the error: there is no output from `./%:r`.

When you want run multiple commands, the output will be taken from the last one. Instead you need to create a subshell to run both commands, so the output of both is combined together:

```
set makeprg=(g++\ -w\ -g\ %\ -o\ %:r\ &&\ ./%:r)
```