# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status; ld error; gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, random, gnu, ld

my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(){
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution dice_roll(1,6);
    std::cout << dice_roll(generator) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The Error when i tried to compile the above code:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,d,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.2.1 20230801 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'random' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/cc1plus -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE programming/c_/random.cpp -quiet -dumpbase random.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -o /tmp/ccWzNenH.s
GNU C++17 (GCC) version 13.2.1 20230801 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 13.2.1 20230801, GMP version 6.3.0, MPFR version 4.2.0-p12, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.26-GMP

warning: MPFR header version 4.2.0-p12 differs from library version 4.2.1.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../include/c++/13.2.1
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../include/c++/13.2.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../include/c++/13.2.1/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: 5a490a353c29b926850bca65a518c219
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'random' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/cclCVfKY.o /tmp/ccWzNenH.s
GNU assembler version 2.41.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.41.0
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'random' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'random.'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccNY4IFq.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -o random /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../.. /tmp/cclCVfKY.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../lib/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cclCVfKY.o: warning: relocation against `_ZSt4cout' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cclCVfKY.o: in function `main':
random.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: random.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: random.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: random.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

- kernel - 6.5.6-arch2-1
- gcc version - 13.2.1

Comment: I get a similar printout if I paste your code into test.cpp and do `gcc test.cpp`. Try `g++ test.cpp` instead. That's the binary for the compiler for c++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Comment: Use g++ instead of gcc